# Divisor reduction

Tags: code-golf, math, integer

A divisor of a number *n* is any number that evenly divides *n*, including 1 and *n* itself. The number of divisors *d(n)* is how many divisors a number has. Here's *d(n)* for the first couple n:

```
n    divisors    d(n)
1    1           1
2    1, 2        2
3    1, 3        2
4    1, 2, 4     3
5    1, 5        2
6    1, 2, 3, 6  4
```

We can repeatedly subtract the number of divisors from a number. For example:

```
16                  = 16
16 - d(16) = 16 - 5 = 11
11 - d(11) = 11 - 2 = 9
 9 - d( 9) =  9 - 3 = 6
 6 - d( 6) =  6 - 4 = 2
 2 - d( 2) =  2 - 2 = 0
```

In this case it took 5 steps to get to 0.

---

Write a program or function that given a nonnegative number *n* returns the number of steps it takes to reduce it to 0 by repeated subtraction of the number of divisors.

Examples:

```
0, 0
1, 1
6, 2
16, 5
100, 19
100000, 7534
```

Comment: Obligatory OEIS link: [A155043](https://oeis.org/A155043)

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79644/8478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

1 byte thanks to [Dennis ♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis).

Port of [my answer in Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80432/48934).

```
ÆDLạµÐĿL’
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4ZETOG6ocK1w5DEv0zigJk&input=&args=MTY)

[Test suite.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4ZETOG6ocK1w5DEv0zigJkKw4figqw&input=&args=MCwxLDYsMTYsMTAw)

### Explanation

```
_ÆDL$$ÐĿL’
      ÐĿ    Repeat the following until result no longer unique:
 ÆD             Yield the array of the divisors
   L            Yield the length of the array
_               Subtract that from the number
        L   Number of iterations
         ’  Minus one.
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 49 bytes

```
f=lambda n:n and-~f(sum(n%~x<0for x in range(n)))
```

orlp helped save a byte! And Sp3000 saved two more. Thanks!

Comment: Should be able to shorten things by moving the `-~` into `n%-~k`, and removing the lower bound of the range.

Answer (score 6):

## C, 52 bytes

```
g,o;l(f){for(g=o=f;o;f%o--||--g);return f?1+l(g):0;}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
tl.ulf%NTS
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tl.ulf%25NTS&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A6%0A16%0A100&debug=0)

### Explanation

```
tl.ulf%NTS
tl.ulf%NTSNQ  implicit variables at the end
           Q  obtain the input number
  .u      N   repeat the following until result no longer unique:
         S        generate range from 1 to N
     f            filter for:
      %NT             T in that range, which N%T is truthy (not zero)
    l             length of that list
                  that means, we found the number of "non-divisors" of N
tl            number of iterations, minus 1.
```

Answer (score 3):

### Julia, 31 bytes

```
f(n)=n<1?0:f(sum(n%(1:n).>0))+1
```

Straightforward recursive implementation.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>64</s> 51 bytes

```
f=n=>n&&[...Array(m=n)].map((_,i)=>m-=n%++i<1)|f(m)+1
```

Don't ask me why I was unnecessarily using tail recursion.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
`t~?x@q.]t:\zT
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YHR-P3hAcS5ddDpcelQ&input=MTAw)

#### Explanation

```
`            T  % Infinite loop
 t~?    ]       % Duplicate number. Is it non-zero?
    x@q.        % If so: delete number, push iteration index minus 1, break loop
         t:\    % Duplicate, range, modulo (remainder). Divisors give a 0 remainder
            z   % Number of non-zero elements; that is, of non-divisors
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>147</s> 93

```
a->{int k,i,n=new Integer(a),l=0;for(;n!=0;n-=k)for(l+=k=i=1;i<n;)if(n%i++==0)++k;return l;}
```

Comment: Why `n=new Integer(100000)` instead of `n=100000`?

Answer (score 2):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), <s>93</s> 76 bytes

```
|=
r/@
?~
r
0
+($(r (sub r (lent (skim (gulf 1^r) |=(@ =(0 (mod r +<))))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
|=  r/@
?~  r
  0
=+  (skim (gulf 1^r) |=(@ =(0 (mod r +<))))
+($(r (sub r (lent -))))
```

Returns a function that takes an atom, `r`. Create an intermediate value that contains all the devisors of `r` (Make list [1..n], keep only the elements where (mod r i) == 0). If `r` is zero return zero, else return the incremented value of recursing with r equal r-(length divisors).

The code as-is takes a stupid amount of time to evaluate for n=100.000, entirely because finding the devisors for big numbers makes a giant list and maps over it. Memoizing the divisors gets the correct output for n=10.000, but I didn't bother waiting around for 100.000

Answer (score 1):

### 05AB1E, <s>12</s> 10 bytes

**Code:**

```
[Ð>#Ñg-¼]¾
```

**Explanation:**

```
[           # start infinite loop
 Ð          # triplicate current number
  >#        # increase by 1 and break if true
    Ñg      # get number of divisors
      -     # subtract number of divisors from number
       ¼    # increase counter
        ]   # end loop
         ¾  # print counter
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=W8OQPiPDkWctwrxdwr4&input=MTY)

Edit: 2 bytes saved and a bug with input 0 fixed thanks to @Adnan

Comment: Very nice! I tried to golf it a bit, and got it down to 10 bytes: `[Ð>#Ñg-¼]¾`. There has to be a way to get it shorter though...

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah, it's because the `D0Q#` part is after the increment of the counter. The `[Ð>#Ñg-¼]¾` code should work for `0` though :).

Comment: @Adnan: I tried a version based on generating all counts upto n and going from index to value at index and counting up, but didn't manage to get it shorter that way.

Answer (score 1):

### R, 50 bytes

Pretty simple implementation. [Try it online](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=QzLqOkKe)

```
z=scan();i=0;while(z>0){z=z-sum(z%%1:z<1);i=i+1};i
```

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8q2ODkxT0PTujwjMydVo0qzusq2Sre4NFdDsUpV1dCqStPazdZN27DWWtvtv8F/AA)

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>74</s> 67 bytes

```
param($n)for($o=0;$n-gt0){$a=0;1..$n|%{$a+=!($n%$_)};$n-=$a;$o++}$o
```

Seems pretty lengthy in comparison to some of the other answers...

Takes input `$n`, enters a `for` loop with the condition that `$n` is greater than `0`. Each loop iteration we set helper `$a`, then loop through every number from `1` up to `$n`. Each inner loop we check against every number to see if it's a divisor, and if so we increment our helper `$a` (using Boolean negation and implicit cast-to-int). Then, we subtract how many divisors we've found `$n-=$a` and increment our counter `$o++`. Finally, we output `$o`.

Takes a *long* time to execute, since it's a significant for-loop construct. For example, running `n = 10,000` on my machine (1yr old Core i5) takes almost 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathcad, [tbd] bytes

[image]

---

Mathcad byte equivalence scheme is yet to be determined.  Using a rough keystroke equivalence, the program uses about 39 "bytes".  Note that the while and for programming operators only take one keyboard operation each to input (ctl-] and ctl-shft-#, respectively) - indeed, they can only be entered this way from the keyboard.

What you see is exactly what gets put down on a Mathcad worksheet.  Mathcad evaluates the equations/programs and puts the output on the same sheet (eg, after the '=' evaluation operator or on the plot).

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>43</s> <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```
g 0=0;g n=1+g(sum$min 1.mod n<$>[1..n])
```

Simple recursive approach. Usage example: `g 16` -> `5`.

Edit: @Lynn saved <s>3</s> 4 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: How about `g(sum$signum.mod n<$>[1..n])`?

Comment: Oh, and `min 1` is actually one byte shorter than `signum`, even

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 13 bytes

```
tX`t:\ztt]Nq&
```

[Try it online](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFhgdDpcenR0XU5xJg&input=MTAw)

Explanation:

```
t               % Duplicate input
 X`      ]      % while loop, consumes 1 input
   t:\z         % calculates n-d(n), by counting number non-divisors
       tt       % dupe twice, for while loop condition, next iteration and to keep in stack
          Nq&   % get stack size, decrement, display that value
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 35 bytes

```js
If[#<1,0,#0[#-0~DivisorSigma~#]+1]&
```

Making use of good old `DivisorSigma`. @MartinBüttner notes the following alternatives:

```js
If[#<1,0,#0[#-DivisorSum[#,1&]]+1]&
f@0=0;f@n_:=f[n-DivisorSum[n,1&]]+1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Racket - <strike>126 bytes Down to 98 bytes</strike>  91 bytes

<strike>An extremely naive solution - could probably be cut down a lot with a decent algorithm and some lisp tricks that I don't know</strike>

```
(define(g x[c 0][d 0][i 2])(cond[(= x 0)c][(= i x)(g d(+ 1 c))][(=(modulo x i)0)(g x c d(+ 1 i))][else(g x c(+ 1 d)(+ 1 i))]))
```

Edit: explanation by request. As I said, this is an extremely naive recursive solution and can be much much shorter.

```
(define (g x [c 0] [d 0] [i 2]) ;g is the name of the function - arguments are x (input), c (counter for steps), d (non-divisor counter), i (iterator)
  (cond
    [(= x 0) c] ;once x gets to 0 c is outputted
    [(= i x) (g d (+ 1 c))] ;if iterator reaches x then we recurse with d as input and add 1 to c
    [(= (modulo x i) 0) (g x c d (+ 1 i))] ;checks if iterator is non divisor, then adds it to d and increments iterator
    [else(g x c (+ 1 d) (+ 1 i))])) ;otherwise just increments iterator
```

<strike>Edit 2: 98 byte version with a less dumb algorithm (still pretty dumb though and can be shorter)</strike>

```
(define(g x)(if(< x 1)0(+ 1(g(length(filter(λ(y)(>(modulo x y)0))(cdr(build-list x values))))))))
```

Explanation:

```
(define (g x) ;function name g, input x
  (if (< x 1)
      0 ;returns 0 if x < 1 (base case)
      (+ 1 ;simple recursion - adds 1 to output for each time we're looping
         (g (length ;the input we're passing is the length of... 
              (filter (λ (y) (> (modulo x y) 0)) ;the list where all numbers which are 0 modulo x are 0 are filtered out from...
                             (cdr (build-list x values)))))))) ;the list of all integers up to x, not including 0
```

Edit 3: Saved 7 bytes by replacing `(cdr(build-list x values))` with `(build-list x add1)`

```
(define(g x)(if(< x 1)0(+ 1(g(length(filter(λ(y)(>(modulo x y)0))(build-list x add1)))))))
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Great post! Can you explain your solution please? (P.S. I love Lisp!)

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Edited in

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 22 bytes

```
{2>⍵:⍵⋄1+∇⍵-0+.=⍵|⍨⍳⍵}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 52+2 = 54 bytes

The input number needs to be present on the stack at program start, so there's +2 bytes for the `-v` flag. [Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=OjApP3Z-bG47Pn4kLV0KMDNbfVw6OgpAQDokPCAgICB2Pz0wOi0xfSt7fiQ_QEAwMSVAOg&input=&args=LXYgMTAw)

```
:0)?v~ln;>~$-]
03[}\::
@@:$<    v?=0:-1}+{~$?@@01%@:
```

4 annoying bytes wasted on alignment issues. Bah.

This one works by building the sequence from `n` to `0` on the stack. Once 0 has been reached, pop it and ouput the length of the remaining stack.

By the way , it runs in `O(n^2)` time, so I wouldn't try `n = 100000`...

Comment: `-v` is one byte, not two.

Answer (score 0):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 36 + 3 = 39  bytes

```
:?v~ln; >~&
:}\0&
+&>1-:?!^:{:}$%0)&
```

The implementation's relatively straightforward, with each iteration being `sum(n%k>0 for k in range(1,n-1))`. +3 bytes for the `-v` flag, per [meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions).

[Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=Oj92fmxuOyA-fiYKOn1cMCYKKyY-MS06PyFeOns6fSQlMCkm&input=&args=LXY+MTAw)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 40 bytes

```
sub f{@_?(1,f((1)x grep@_%$_,1..@_)):()}
```

Input and output are as lists of the requisite number of copies of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 42 bytes

```
f=->n{n<1?0:1+f[n-(1..n).count{|i|n%i<1}]}
```

There's a stack overflow error on the largest test case `100000`, so here's an iterative version within **49 bytes**. Takes a while, though, considering the `O(N^2)` complexity.

```
->n{c=0;c+=1 while 0<n-=(1..n).count{|i|n%i<1};c}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 63 bytes

```
int F(int n)=>n<1?0:F(Enumerable.Range(1,n).Count(i=>n%i>0))+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Actually, 17 bytes

```
";╗R`╜%`░l;"£╬klD
```

Try it online! (note: last test case times out on TIO)

Explanation:

```
";╗R`╜%`░l;"£╬klD
"          "£╬     while top of stack is truthy, call the function:
 ;╗                  push a copy of n to reg0
   R                 range(1,n+1) ([1,n])
    `  `░l             push the number of values where the following is truthy:
     ╜%                  k mod n
                       (this computes the number of non-divisors of n)
          ;            make a copy
              klD  push entire stack as list, count number of items, subtract 1
                   (the result is the number of times the function was called)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
←LU¡Ṡ-oLḊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbBJ/QQwsf7lygm@/zcEfX////Dc0A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
©ÒßU-â l
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=qdLfVS3iIGw&input=MTAw)

Or 9 bytes without recursion:

```
©@µâ l}f1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=qUC14iBsfWYx&input=MTAwMDAw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `l`, 5 bytes

```
≬KL-İ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJsIiwiIiwi4omsS0wtxLAiLCIiLCIxMDAiXQ==)

Flagless:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
≬KL-İL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiaxLTC3EsEwiLCIiLCIxMDAiXQ==)