# Little Endian Number to String Conversion

Tags: code-golf

### Introduction

During work with [BMP (bitmap)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) generator I face problem of converting number to little endian hex string. Here is function which I create in JavaScript - but wonder how small code can works similarly

```js
let liEnd= num => num.toString(16).padStart(8,'0').match(/../g).reverse().join``;
console.log(liEnd(304767)) // 304767 dec = 0x4a67f hex
```

### Challenge

Write function which will take 32bit unsigned integer number on input, and produce 8-digit hexadecimal string with little endian order. The example algorithm which do the job:

- convert numb to hex string e.g: `304767 -> '4a67f'`
- add padding zeros to get 8-char string: `'0004a67f'`
- split string to four 2-char pieces: `'00','04','a6','7f'`
- reverse order of pieces `'7f','a6','04','00'`
- join pieces and return as result: `'7fa60400'`

### Example Input and Output

Input number (or string with dec number) is on the left of `->`, output hex string is on the right

```
2141586432 -> 0004a67f
304767     -> 7fa60400
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
žJ+h¦2ôRJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6D4v7YxDy4wObwny@v/f0MjYxNQMAA)

-1 byte by inspiration of the Jelly answer.

```
žJ+   add 2^32 to input
h     convert to hex
¦     drop leading 1
2ô    split in groups of 2
R     reverse groups
J     and join them
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```r
format.hexmode(scan()%/%256^(0:3)%%256%*%256^(3:0),8)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/KDexRC8jtSI3PyVVozg5MU9DU1Vf1cjULE7DwMpYUxXEVNWCCBhbGWjqWGj@NzI0MTS1MDMxNvoPAA)

Each group of 2 characters is actually the hex representation of a digit in base 256. `scan()%/%256^(0:3)%%256` converts to a base 256 number with 4 digits reversed, 
`...%*%256^(3:0)` joins them as a single integer, and `format.hexmode(...,8)` converts that number to its hex representation with 8 digits.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda n:n.to_bytes(4,"little").hex()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk@vJD8@qbIktVjDREcpJ7OkJCdVSVMvI7VCQ/N/QVFmXolGmoaRoYmhqYWZibGRpiYXTNDYwMTczFxT8z8A)

**Arithmetic-based recursive solution (<s>50</s> 49 bytes, works also for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/))**:

```python
f=lambda n,i=4:i*'1'and"%02x"%(n%256)+f(n>>8,i-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NchLCoAgFADAfaeIQPSVQX7SCPQuRkhCvSJc1Olt1SznevN2oioluj0cyxpq5MnpObVU0IBrQwb5NIQhkaOBLjL0fuKpF1CuO2FmkUmhxTgZrSRA9acatDUWoHw)

*-1 byte thanks to @JonathanAllan*

Comment: I'd say submit the recursive one as a Python 2 entry :)

Comment: `f=lambda n,i=4:i*'1'and'%02x'%(n%256)+f(n>>8,i-1)` saves a byte :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks. I am not familiar with all Python 2 tricks and do not see how it can be made shorter though.

Comment: it doesn't but the 37 won't work in py 2

Comment: Yeah. Some of those built-ins are Python-3-only.

Comment: @negativeseven Interesting approach. You may post it as another answer for Python 2.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>59</s>  57 bytes

String manipulation.

```javascript
n=>(n+2**32).toString(16).match(/\B../g).reverse().join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcwxEsIgEEDR3lOkhDgumwTBJhZewdYiDEIkExeHMLk@Yumv3/zF7GazKXzyieLTFT8WGq@Mjn3bDj2HHO85BZpZpzi8TbYvJh43ADFzSG53aXOMwxIDTVOxkba4OljjzDzrO9mdL0rWDW@EaBBRGqX94Z8NKLXSlfyqTHujUCKWLw)

#### How?

We first convert \$n + 2^{32}\$ to hexadecimal to make sure that all leading \$0\$'s are included:

```javascript
(304767 + 2**32).toString(16) // --> '10004a67f'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrvFfw9jAxNzMXEFbwUhLy9hIU68kP7ikKDMvXcPQTPO/5n8A)

We use the regular expression `/\B../g` to match all groups of 2 digits, ignoring the leading \$1\$ thanks to `\B` (non-*word boundary*).

```javascript
'10004a67f'.match(/\B../g) // --> [ '00', '04', 'a6', '7f' ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrvFf3dDAwMAk0cw8TV0vN7EkOUNDP8ZJT08/XfO/5n8A)

We `reverse()` and `join()` to get the final string.

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 61 bytes

Recursive function.

```javascript
f=(n,k=4)=>k?[(x=n&255)>>4&&'']+x.toString(16)+f(n>>8,k-1):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcq7DoMgFADQvV/hJBBfF72AaQL9iI5NB2LF@Ag0ahr/ntqxZz6T/ditW8f3Xvjw6mN0mvp81si0mW8Pemif1kIwYzBNCXlmR7mH@76OfqBcssxRb0ybzwVnV0JiF/wWlr5cwkAdrTly0UpsasaSqkoAAK1U7vLfGkAl1Vl@zqaclYAA8Qs)

Comment: ⭐ - you get star for nice answer - I like it, short but still clean and "human-redable" :)

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 54 bytes

```cs
x=>$"{(x=x>>16|x<<16)>>8&16711935|(x&16711935)<<8:x8}"
```

Saved 4 bytes thanks to @PeterCordes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU5qZV6JTXFKUmZdul2b7v8LWTkWpWqPCtsLOztCspsLGxtBM087OQs3QzNzQ0NLYtEajAs7WtLGxsKqwqFX6b80VXpRZkuqTmZeqkaZhZGhiaGphZmJspKkJlQGKGhuYmJuZA0X@AwA)

#### Explanation

```cs
x=>                                                    //Lambda taking in an uint
     (x=x>>16|x<<16)                                   //Swap the first two and the last two bytes of the uint (0x7fa60400 -> 0x04007fa6)
                    >>8&16711935|(x&16711935)<<8       //Swap each pair of bytes in every group of 2 bytes (0x04007fa6 -> 0x0004a67f)
  $"{                                           :x8}"  //Format as hex string, padded with leading zeroes to length 8
```

Comment: Can you shrink the `4278255360` mask constant to `16711935` (`0xff00ff`) if you shift *before* masking?   Or does that cost extra parens?  Also, if not then `0xff00ff00` is the same length but much more meaningful to humans.

Comment: @PeterCordes It also has the added advantage of being able to remove the brackets as `>>` has higher precedence than `&`, whcih saved 4 bytes total. Thanks!

Comment: Cool.  In your "explanation" section, I'd suggest writing the constants in hex.

Answer (score 5):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 46 bytes

```sh
i=$1
repeat 4 printf %02x $[j=i%256,i=i/256,j]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9P9NWxZCrKLUgNbFEwUShoCgzryRNQdXAqEJBJTrLNlPVyNRMJ9M2Ux9EZ8X@r@XiSssvUshTyMxTMDYwMTczVzAyNDE0tTAzMTayruZSUEhTUMkDUqnJGflctf8B)

Answer (score 5):

## x86 32-bit machine code, <s>24</s> 21 bytes

changelog: -3 bytes: replace standard add/cmp/jbe/add with a DAS hack by @peter ferrie

64-bit: still 24 bytes.  Long mode removed the DAS opcode.
16-bit mode: the default operand-size is 16-bit but the problem spec is inherently 32-bit.  Including hard-coded 8 hex digits.

---

**Byte-reverse with `bswap` then manual int->hex in standard order** (most-significant nibble first, writing hex digits to a char output buffer in ascending order.)  This avoids needing to unroll the loop to switch order between nibbles within a byte vs. across bytes.

Callable as `void lehex(char buf[8] /*edi*/, uint32_t x /*esi*/);` like x86-64 System V, except this doesn't work in 64-bit mode.  (It needs the output pointer in EDI for `stosb`.  The input number can be in any register other than ECX or EAX.)

```
     1                             lehex:
     2 00000000 0FCE                   bswap  esi
     3 00000002 6A08                   push   8            ; 8 hex digits
     4 00000004 59                     pop    ecx
     5                             .loop:                ;do{
     6 00000005 C1C604                 rol    esi, 4       ; rotate high nibble to the bottom
     7                             
     8 00000008 89F0                   mov    eax, esi
     9 0000000A 240F                   and    al, 0x0f     ; isolate low nibble
    10 0000000C 3C0A                   cmp al, 10          ; set CF according to digit <= 9
    11 0000000E 1C69                   sbb al, 0x69        ; read CF, set CF and conditionally set AF
    12 00000010 2F                     das                 ; magic, which happens to work
    13                             
    14 00000011 AA                     stosb               ; *edi++ = al
    15 00000012 E2F1                   loop  .loop       ; }while(--ecx)
    16                             
    17 00000014 C3                     ret
```

size = 0x15 = 21 bytes.

[TIO FASM 32-bit x86 test case](https://tio.run/##bVRda9swFH33r7iPbeqExEnbuGaFsK1Q6Dro9lZKkO3rWNSWjCTXCWO/PbuSPcdJI2gVS/fznHPFtMYyLnbjjOlyv8@kKpmB708PgFtMasPiAmHuRfCw@vUDWFHIRkOtwUgo2TtdBeOYm4GxBing9@NPH2pRcLJ4JkfPKzDH7Z0HtGLdsAoANXefVa1z2pYwWBF9kj2kfMONbs1kZTdMtt6kkLK6g5MVpfKPs1SycJaa@7DoAyppmEHI@SYHwWPbFvVgcoRYGiNLz/mW8sP5sq3fF8hE6rbCh@l2mnXxuJaFDUiAdPGccVJWznI2HXaj0cDXB2BJIlXKxcamdr3dh85Lx3EX/yY8eClkKbn5vTsVkkiRcsOlICp27mJFBvamUYTq6smGvocwzF3glGn4BBQxt@GJD03OkxxyVlUoHKONVO8tDtpIHX/yG2HKr67gC9XqrCwPAJN262z@UtQCL8ZjYuqyDabQ7CMwqEknH6h2B2ohU7KEqc2d@cBFUtQOHuY6CoGk2DJUi5SpnYfCkPtaG6aM126tpg5CGgAfgcCm4AJ7E13HThmVD8v@sOWcWrOUVyT1o2OromC2mF0vbxbz4NTJ3pIoZsF8cX1z298mxA7BYzXv9YdR1J5T22zDuPDJwBjbLp1IAqZRnATF1CZx7dOPjwnAytLToRLQsTaKPibDsC6RhblWRGTDTQ4v3x5pZLhw8aXAccW0GROYYwoGMnO4kpdVASqEBgk/KuwTZJSgRU1Z1MIzakpIp7ZuISmm6uoDRYNmYBQjDcjIZcu4IgUo1HVhhuFbKOMdxaiMgldKdLV860YoOldQ66EsY2Tc35B@WiLh/KI5fOeVq0UWaR/4DOHz6eJ2QOcR2cuQxUmK2Vmyjz1cT69U0Nvxg2BLcVOX9qj9L@Y0p32IDo/Y@vll3aqknZxacG3S9TyY5KeOMTnOescsPb1P3AtXdfdxnX2aBzIIR0FnUKCguQ8HM2ph7Kr2wfCSXv4AYkxYrZ2cLCyYWm2bhidInt17q1mJNmGGajLgztB/QvcEJtftxcy3DlTP5VmAZkcA4ZYf9LWVqkOD/s5k2/8D) with an asm caller that uses a `write` system call to write the output after calling it twice to append 2 strings into a buffer.  Tests all hex digits 0..F, including 9 and A at the boundary between numeral vs. letter.

**The [`DAS`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/DAS) hack** - x86 has a half-carry flag, for carry out of the low nibble.  Useful for packed-BCD stuff like the DAS instruction, intended for use after subtracting two 2-digit BCD integers.  With the low nibble of AL being outside the 0-9 range, we're definitely abusing it here.

Notice the `if (old_AL > 99H) or (old_CF = 1)` THEN  `AL ← AL − 60H;` part of the Operation section in the manual; sbb *always* sets CF here so that part always happens.  That and the ASCII range for upper-case letters is what motivates the choice of `sbb al, 0x69`

- `cmp 0xD, 0xA` doesn't set CF
- sbb `0xD - 0x69` wraps to AL=`0xA4` as input to DAS. (And sets CF, clears AF)
- no AL -= 6 in the first part of DAS (because 4 > 9 is false and AF=0)
- AL -= 0x60 in the second part, leaving `0x44`, the ASCII code for `'D'`

vs. a numeral:

- `cmp 0x3, 0xA` sets CF
- sbb `3 - 0x69 - 1` = AL = 0x99 and sets CF and AF
- AL -= 6 in the first part of DAS (9 > 9 is false but AF is set), leaving 0x93
- AL -= 0x60 in the second part, leaving 0x33, the ASCII code for `'3'`.

Subtracting `0x6a` in SBB will set AF for every digit <= 9 so all the numerals follow the same logic.  And leave it cleared for every alphabetic hex digit.  i.e. correctly exploiting the 9 / A split handling of DAS.

---

[Normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823756/how-to-convert-a-number-to-hex) (for performance) you'd use a lookup table for a scalar loop, or possibly a branchless 2x `lea` and `cmp/cmov` conditional add.  But 2-byte `al, imm8` instructions are a big win for code-size.

---

**x86-64 version version**: just the part that's different, between `and al, 0xf` and `stosb`.

```
;; x86-64 int -> hex  in 8 bytes
    10 0000000C 0430                   add    al, '0'
    11 0000000E 3C39                   cmp    al, '9'
    12 00000010 7602                   jbe  .digit
    13 00000012 0427                     add    al, 'a'-10 - '0'     ; al =  al>9 ? al+'a'-10 : al+'0'
    14                             .digit:
```

Notice that the `add al, '0'` *always* runs, and the conditional add only adds the difference between `'a'-10` and `'0'`, to make it just an `if` instead of `if`/`else`.

Tested and works, using the same `main` caller as [my C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193793/little-endian-num-2-string-conversion/193831#193831), which uses `char buf[8]` and `printf("%.8s\n", buf)`.

Comment: can you create online-working snippet in e.g. [here](https://tio.run/##TYzBCsIwDIbPy1PEnSd0zIN4V3bw7lHSNROhtdBUqU9fu1GG/@nLn@QjEXbafvczict59sFRxPP1gpx4ekfSlnEAuEukEE/QOP9BptThobIu3FeeCjt51MksmwGa5yviGpWO6s/QA9ZsIrVVy9N6j1CMaDS2I1vrO7z5YM2uzfkH) ?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski: TIO makes it impossible (AFAIK) to write the caller in C to test an asm function so I often don't bother, but sure since you asked and `sys_write` can output fixed-length strings easily.  Oh interesting, I hadn't realized FASM on TIO let you create 32-bit executables, unlike with NASM where it doesn't respect `-felf32`.  I prefer x86-64 anyway, and this answer doesn't save any bytes from 32-bit code.

Comment: ⭐ - you get star for nice answer

Comment: Currently the shortest answer in a non-golfing language. :)

Comment: You could just call C from this (strtoll) and it could very well be shorter.

Comment: @JL2210: Do you mean `sprintf`?  I don't think libc has any handy int->string functions other than format-string based ones, only string->int like strtoul.  But yes, bswap / printf would probably be shorter, if you can figure out some way to count bytes for the GOT entry for a function in a dynamic library (besides the 6-byte `call [rel printf wrt ..got]` call site); a minimal statically linked executables can be significantly smaller than dynamic, at least when made by `ld` with normal defaults.  But I don't think it would be reasonable to statically link it but not count its code size.

Comment: @JL2210: Remember, this is an x86 *machine code* answer, not asm text source size.  I haven't used libc functions in previous machine-code answers, only Linux system calls (e.g. in Fibonacci), and IDK how I'd go about counting the cost or whether I even want to write machine-code-with-libc answers.  There are use-cases for x86 machine code where a libc isn't available, e.g. in a bootloader.

Comment: you can cut three bytes by replacing "add/cmp/jbe/add" with "cmp al, 0ah / sbb al, 69h / das"

Comment: @peterferrie: Interesting, thanks.  DAS isn't available in 64-bit mode, but it works for other modes.  It took me a while to understand and write up a proper explanation for how your idea worked!

Comment: Love the DAS hack. You can also do "add al, 0x90 / daa / adc al, 040 / daa" (though it's one byte longer than the peter ferrie method). [TIO link](https://tinyurl.com/mr3e75fs)

Comment: I believe you forgot to delete the _"no"_ from the numeric case _"no AL -= 6 in the first part of DAS (9 > 9 is false but AF is set), leaving 0x93"_ ... that looks like a yes to me :)

Comment: @Jester: Yes, thanks.  Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 37 bytes

```
func[x][reverse/skip form to-hex x 2]
```

This breaks TIO because of the outdated compiler it uses.

### [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 43 bytes

```
func[x][load next mold reverse to-binary x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxbDkAwEAXQrdwNSDxKxTL8Nv1Ap4mEjoySWn2xgHOEXB7JwVh45iH7KywmWbPx5BAoRey8OQjdJCchcjGvYZIHyeZD1hBhPoemVLrTf4G6UlXbd6qpbX4B)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 30 bytes

```c
f(x){printf("%.8x",htonl(x));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcrdCsIgGIDhc69CFrFPqLEf2wZGV9LJ0NmE9TlMYzB27SbRae/hwyvPDylj1LCybXEGvYbsWPRrdpq8xTkxE3s8GJRzUCO9vrwytphuhKSXPgeD8LZGMbIRmtJQV7y69C1vaia@tAQvp8FBfsf8Rxqakndt9/9wow8OaSnIHj8)

Comment: when run on a big-endian machine, this won't convert to little-endian?

Comment: @peterferrie See revision 3.

Comment: @peterferrie: Correct.  Code Golf answers have to work on *at least one* implementation of the language, not all.  rev 3 used `__builtin_bswap32` for portability.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
sG ùT8 ò w
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=c0cg%2bVQ4IPIgdw&input=MzA0NzY3)

```
sG ùT8 ò w     :Implicit input of integer
s              :Convert to string
 G             :  In base-16
   ù           :Left pad
    T          :  With 0
     8         :  To length 8
       ò       :Split into 2s
         w     :Reverse
               :Implicitly join and output
```

Comment: What does `-P` do?

Comment:  your answer is in the top (can you add explanation?)

Comment: @JL2210 [From the docs](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/): "_`-P`: If the output is an array, outputs with no separator (i.e. joined with `P`)._". So the flag is for an implicit instead of explicit join to save bytes. :)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski, explanation added.

Answer (score 4):

## x86 SIMD machine code (AVX512-VBMI), 36 bytes

(16 bytes of which are a hex lookup table)

This is a function that takes an integer in `xmm0` and returns 8 bytes of ASCII char data in `xmm0`, for the caller to store wherever it wants.  (e.g. to video memory after interleaving with attribute bytes, or into a string under construction, or whatever)

From C, call it as `__m128i retval = lehex(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(x))` with the x86-64 System V calling convention, or MS Windows `vectorcall`.

```
# disassembly with machine-code bytes (the answer) and NASM source code.
0000000000401000 <lehex>:
  401000:       c5 f1 72 d0 04          vpsrld      xmm1, xmm0, 4         ; AVX1
  401005:       c5 f1 60 c8             vpunpcklbw  xmm1, xmm1, xmm0      ; AVX1
  401009:    62 f2 75 08 8d 05 01 00 00 00 vpermb  xmm0, xmm1, [rel .hex_lut]
  401013:       c3                      ret    

0000000000401014 <lehex.hex_lut>:
  401014:     30 31 ...  61 62 ...     .hex_lut:  db "0123456789abcdef"
```

Total = 0x24 = 36 bytes.

**See [How to convert a number to hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823756/how-to-convert-a-number-to-hex) on SO for how this works.**  (SSE2 for the shift / punpck, then `vpermb` saves work that we'd need for `pshufb`.  AVX1 instead of SSE2/SSSE3 also avoids a `movaps` register copy.)

Notice that `punpcklbw` with the source operands in that order will give us the most-significant nibble of the low input byte in the lowest byte element, then the least-significant nibble of the lowest source byte.  (In that SO answer, a `bswap` is used on the input to get a result in standard printing order with only SSE2.  But here we *want* that order: high nibble in lower element within each byte, but still little-endian byte order).

If we had more data constants, we could save addressing-mode space by doing one `mov edx, imm32` then using `[rdx+16]` or whatever addressing modes.  Or `vpbroadcastb xmm0, [rdx+1]`.

But I think a 16-byte hex LUT + `vpermb` is still better than implementing the `n>9 : n+'a'-10 : n+'0'` condition: that requires 3 constants and at least 3 instructions with AVX512BW byte-masking (compare into mask, `vpaddb`, merge-masked `vpaddb`), or more with AVX1 or SSE2.  (See [How to convert a number to hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823756/how-to-convert-a-number-to-hex) on SO for an SSE2 version of that).  And each AVX512BW instruction is at least 6 bytes long (4-byte EVEX + opcode + modrm), longer with a displacement in the addressing mode.

Actually it would take at least *4* instructions because we need to clear high garbage with `andps`, (or EVEX `vpandd` with a 4-byte broadcast memory operand) before the compare.  And each of those needs a different vector constant.  AVX512 has broadcast memory operands, but only for elements of 32-bit and wider.  e.g. [EVEX `vpaddb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/paddb:paddw:paddd:paddq)'s last operand is only `xmm3/m128`, not `xmm3/m128/m8bcst`.  (Intel's load ports can only do 32 and 64-bit broadcasts for free as part of a load uop so Intel designed AVX512BW to reflect that and not be able to encode byte or word broadcast memory operands at all, instead of giving them the option to do dword broadcasts so you can still compress your constants to 4 bytes :/.)

**The reason I used [AVX512VBMI `vpermb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermb) instead of SSSE3 / AVX1 `pshufb` is twofold:**

- `vpermb` ignores high bits of the selectors.  `(v)pshufb` zeros bytes according to the high bit of the control vector and would have needed an extra `pand` or `andps` to actually isolate nibbles.  With XMM / 16-byte size, `vpermb` only looks at the low 4 bits of the shuffle-control elements, i.e. bits `[3:0]` in Intel's notation in the [Operation section](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermb).
- `vpermb` can take the data to be shuffled (the lookup table) as a memory operand.  `(v)pshufb`'s xmm/mem operand is the shuffle-control vector.

Note that AVX512VBMI is only available on CannonLake / Ice Lake so you probably need a simulator to test this, like Intel's SDE.

Comment: ⭐ - you get star for nice answer

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski: lol thanks.  Converting numbers to hex efficiently is one of my favourite things.  It's a nice use-case for several neat tricks and bit-manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda n:[("%08x"%n)[i^6]for i in range(8)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjRCsIgFAbge5/iIAwURmzOnAx6EjMwyjpRv0N2UU9v7Lv81t/2LDAtn87tnT7XWyIsQclu8F/ZQQe@uJhLJSYG1YTHXXkd217YKwgyox2P3tnJ9IKmwc5u7kVcBK2VsZGUh1dhqKygdfsD)

*-4 bytes thanks to [benrg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89587/benrg)*

Outputs a list of characters. Computed by retrieving, in order, the hex digits of the input at indices `6, 7, 4, 5, 2, 3, 0, 1`.

Comment: `[i^6]for i in range(8)` saves a few bytes.

Comment: Is it allowed to output list instead of string?

Comment: output as list is not really fit for the spirit of the question imo

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) endian agnostic, no standard libs, <s>92</s> 91 bytes

`h(n)` is a single-digit integer->hex helper function.
`f(x,p)` takes an integer and a `char[8]` pointer.  The result is 8 bytes of `char` data.  (*Not* 0-terminated unless the caller does that.)

Assumptions: ASCII character set.  2's complement `int` so right shift eventually brings down the sign bit, and converting a `uint32_t` to `int` doesn't munge the bit-pattern if the high bit is set.  `int` is at least 32-bit.  (Wider might let it work on 1's complement or sign-magnitude C implementations).

Non-assumptions: anything about implementation byte-order or signedness of `char`.

```c
i;h(n){n&=15;return n>9?n+87:n+48;}f(x,p)char*p;{for(i=5;--i;x>>=8)*p++=h(x>>4),*p++=h(x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHdcpswEIXv9RQ7ybRAMP6JcUyi4rxAO73IRS7STEcGCdTShZGE48TDq5dIYGcm03aqK1bLnj3fURYVWdafS8yqNufwSZtc1tNy00ta@hgc8GO6WFHFTasQcHN9i2GyvsEwTmgn/P2kCbKSqYuGHkStfJmuaBRJut9s0iS4aMIwLX1bxMHkVAS06yUakJTMZuc5FxI5uFWAdcMngJznGvjeKAYNUxw1abGoK8Hz7391BLeAoce8aDGHG/c592gHw5nNQEssKg65LKTdiYYXXEG0gZLvCdnVMoc39fc4xAmcmMBBwUg16n6@g@2z4SCk0gZYpmqthxtN4Hje4b8Z@nIHKLfb6jT6JE0p8R@jASUdIX@@DnEJ/mISfYcQkNGtsw7bVjxcP6aHh@Qx9V68jo5r3RpgYFOVlY0EMoZMPY8MprajPPvpcN28sBHVO65EVT/ZutDTMQz/chEvVslVvLycuP@sO3ffKOtG@Gcfpon@hmfH1rh26MGP1oKakkMCO1bZzAfak@pyHq@v1v9XHFrHd5@7YPrfmahYofvo67KP7llVvQI)  including test caller using `printf("%.8s\n", buf)` to print output buffer without 0-terminating it.

**Ungolfed:**

```c
int h(n){n&=15;return n>9 ? n+'a'-10 : n+'0';}      // single digit integer -> hex

int i;
void ungolfed_f(x,p)char*p;{
    for(i=5; --i; x>>=8)   // LS byte first across bytes
        *p++=h(x>>4),      // MS nibble first within bytes
        *p++=h(x);
}
```

Doing `n&=15;` inside `h(x)` is break-even; 6 bytes there vs. 3 each for `&15` to isolate the low nibble at both call sites.

`,` is a sequence point (or equivalent in modern terminology) so it's safe to do `*p++= stuff` twice in one statement when separated by the `,` operator.

`>>` on signed integer is implementation-defined as either arithmetic or logical.  GNU C defines it as arithmetic 2's complement.  But on any 2's complement machine it doesn't really matter because we never look at the shifted-in 0s or copies of the sign bit.  The original MSB will eventually get down into the low byte unchanged.  This is not the case on sign/magnitude, and I'm not sure about 1's complement.

So this may only be portable to 2's complement C implementations.  (Or where `int` is *wider* than 32 bits so bit 31 is just part of the magnitude.)  unsigned -> signed conversion also munges the bit-pattern for negative integers, so `&15` on an `int` would only extract nibbles of the original unsigned value on 2's complement.  Again, unless `int` was *wider* than 32-bit so all inputs are non-negative.

The golfed version has UB from falling off the end of a non-void function.  Not to return a value, just to avoid declaring it `void` instead of default `int`.  Modern compilers will break this with optimization enabled.

---

Motivation: I was considering an x86 or ARM Thumb asm answer, thought it might be fun to do it manually in C, maybe for compiler-generated asm as a starting point.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823756/how-to-convert-a-number-to-hex for speed-efficient x86 asm, including an AVX512VBMI version that's only 2 instructions (but needs control vectors for vpmultishiftqb and vpshufb so wouldn't be great for golf).  Normally it takes extra work for SIMD to byte-reverse into printing order on little-endian x86 so this byte-reversed hex output is actually easier than normal.

---

**Other ideas**

I considered taking the integer by reference and looping over its bytes with `char*`, on a little-endian C implementation (like x86 or ARM).  But I don't think that would have saved much.

Using `sprintf` to do 1 byte at a time, 64 bytes after golfing:

```c
int i;
void f(x,p)char*p;{
        for(i=4;sprintf(p,"%.2x",x&255),--i;x>>=8)
                p+=2;
}
```

But if we're using printf-like functions we might as well byte-swap and do a `%x` printf of the whole thing like [@JL2210's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193793/little-endian-num-2-string-conversion/193801#193801).

Comment: ⭐ - you get star for nice answer

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>58</s> <s>40</s> 36 bytes

```scala
"%08X"format Integer.reverseBytes(_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcpBC4IwGIDhu7/iQwq2S0xdToQFdevQKYIgIr5sE0NnbEMQ8bfboFu3F97HVdji0j/fqvJwwsbAFL2Uhi4kQVu7EvbW4ng7e9uY@k5LuJjGgwxuwBZ0SY7GU7n7fbnEa1ZcY93bDj2EpWplN1YNyjp1GL1y5EGX6BOwbw1x8WrSJE14si1ynqV0BimBMcYxFzqmfzBjXOTih4TGnHHGAormefkC)

Still uses the builtin to reverse the bytes of an `Int`, but uses `format` to format the `Int` as a Hex. No need to call `toHexString`.

Removed the parens on `format`. This now means that the argument can be taken implicitly using `_`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), <strike>52 51</strike> 40 bytes

```forth
: f hex 0 4. do <# # # 0. #> type loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYvBCoMwFMDufkXQs6XVTmWK/zJsOwdKH8XB9vVVySGXJMR0rPU73Mr5SWD1PzRW4SJTxY1WVDPHXzxbjMJ4hYL7CkajEqqEeqa8bueXz/7aWBJj0RhrHkNn2wakaLXtux7JJw)

#### Code explanation

```forth
: f           \ start a new word definition
  hex         \ set the current base to base 16
  0           \ convert the input number to a double-cell integer
  4. do       \ start a counted loop from 0 to 3
    <# # #    \ start a formatted numeric string and move last 2 digits to format area
    0.        \ move remaining digits down the stack
    #>        \ delete top two stack value and convert format area to string
    type      \ output string
  loop        \ end loop
;             \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, <s>36</s> 34 bytes

2 bytes saved by converting to index zero

Prompts for integer:

```
'0123456789abcdef'[,⊖4 2⍴(8⍴16)⊤⎕]
```

[Try it online! Courtesy Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tv7qBoZGxiamZuYVlYlJySmqaerTOo65pJgpGj3q3aFgACUMzzUddS4DaYv8DdfxP4zI2MDE3M@dK4zIyNDE0tTAzMTYCAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
+Ø%b⁴Ḋs2Ṛ‘ịØh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//K8OYJWLigbThuIpzMuG5muKAmOG7i8OYaP///zMwNDc2Nw)

A full program that takes an integer as its argument and prints a string.

Comment:  your answer is in the top

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
8{._1{3!:3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Lar14g2rjRWtjP9rcnGlJmfkK6QpGBuYmJuZw3hGhiaGphZmJsZG/wE)

### how

`3!:3` is a J "foreign conjunction" for hex representation, documented [here](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx003.htm).  That is, it's a builtin for converting to hex.  However, it's output it not quite what we want. Eg, running:

```
3!:3 (304767)
```

produces:

```
e300000000000000
0400000000000000
0100000000000000
0000000000000000
7fa6040000000000
```

The meaning of the other lines is explained on the doc page I linked to above.  In any case, it's clear we want the first 8 chars of the last line.

`_1{` get the last line.

`8{.` gets the first 8 characters of it.

Comment:  your answer is in the top

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 91 bytes

```
=RIGHT(DEC2HEX(A1,8),2)&MID(DEC2HEX(A1,8),5,2)&MID(DEC2HEX(A1,8),3,2)&LEFT(DEC2HEX(A1,8),2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download/), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

**Solution:**

```
,/$|4_0x0\:
```

**Examples:**

```
q)k),/$|4_0x0\:304767
"7fa60400"
q)0W
"0004a67f"
```

**Explanation:**

Pretty much exactly what the question asks:

```
,/$|4_0x0\: / the solution
      0x0\: / split to bytes
    4_      / drop first 4 bytes
   |        / reverse
  $         / convert to string
,/          / flatten
```

**Notes:**

- **-1 byte** as K4 numbers are longs (64bit) by default, so dropping 4 bytes (32bits)

Comment:  your answer is in the top

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 31 bytes

```php
<?=unpack(H8,pack(V,$argn))[1];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62NK8gMTlbw8NCB0yH6agkFqXnaWpGG8Za/09NzshXUIrJU7L@b2RoYmhqYWZibMRlbGBibmb@L7@gJDM/r/i/rhsA)

Taking advantage of PHP's [pack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) and [unpack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php), I pack the unsigned input with "32 bit little endian byte order" format (`V`) into a binary string and then unpack it with "hex string, high nibble first" format (`H`) and print the result.

This seems to be one of the rare cases where PHP's built-ins are actually shorter than implementing a simple algorithm!

Comment: PHP's `pack()`/`unpack()` functions are awesome for the 0 times you ever need them in most PHP projects. Congrats, you found their use!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
⪫⮌⪪﹪%08xＮ²ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMrPzNPIyi1LLWoOFUjuCAns0TDNz@lNCdfQ0nVwKJCSUfBM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU1NHwQhElGtqWv//b2xgYm5m/l@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
        Ｎ   Input as a number
   ﹪%08x    Format using literal string
  ⪪      ²  Split into pairs of characters
 ⮌          Reverse
⪫         ω Join
            Implicitly print
```

19 bytes without resorting to Python formatting:

```
⪫…⮌⪪⍘⁺Ｘ²¦³⁶Ｎ¹⁶¦²¦⁴ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMrPzNPw7kyOSfVOSO/QCMotSy1qDhVI7ggJ7NEwymxODW4BKguXSMgp7RYIyC/PLVIw0hHwdhMU0fBM6@gtMSvNDcJKKYJ5BuCBI1ALBMgLtfUtP7/39jAxNzM/L9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
           Ｎ        Input as a number
     ⁺              Plus
       ²            Literal 2
      Ｘ             To power
         ³⁶         Literal 36
    ⍘               Convert to base
            ¹⁶      Literal 16
   ⪪           ²    Split into pairs of digits
  ⮌                 Reverse the list
 …               ⁴  Take the first 4 pairs
⪫                 ω Join together
                    Implicitly print
```

Comment:  your answer is in the top

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (-p), 22 bytes

```perl
$_=unpack H8,pack V,$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rY0ryAxOVvBw0IHTIfpqMT//29kaGJoamFmYmzEZWxgYm5m/i@/oCQzP6/4v25BDgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>31</s> 27 bytes

Ended up being a port of [Night2's PHP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193910/52194) because Ruby has the same pack/unpack functionality.

```ruby
->*i{i.pack(?V).unpack'H8'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104rszpTryAxOVvDPkxTrzQPxFT3sFCv/V@ekZmTqpCeWlLMpVBQWlKskBatEq9Xkh@fGcuVmpfy38jQxNDUwszE2IjL2MDE3MwcAA)

My original 31-byte answer that didn't take advantage of the H8 unpack mode because I didn't know about it:

```ruby
->*i{'%02x'*4%i.pack(?V).bytes}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104rs1pd1cCoQl3LRDVTryAxOVvDPkxTL6myJLW49n95RmZOqkJ6akkxl0JBaUmxQlq0SrxeSX58ZixXal7KfyNDE0NTCzMTYyMuYwMTczNzAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Windows Batch, 90 bytes

```
@for /l %%x in (24,-8,0)do @set/aa=%1^>^>%%x^&255&cmd/cexit !a!&<nul set/p=!=exitcode:~-2!
```

Run the command-line with /v to enable the delayed expansion.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```rust
|n|print!("{:08x}",n.swap_bytes())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZzaWgkJNaopBmlZanUWpspKlgq/C/Jq@moCgzr0RRQ6naysCiolZJJ0@vuDyxID6psiS1WENT8781V5qGsYGJuZm5JlftfwA)

Rust has built-in hex formatting, but it displays in big-endian format, so I reversed the byte order first. Capitalize the `x` if you want uppercase hex digits instead of lowercase ones.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.11+](https://www.python.org), 34 bytes

```python
lambda n:n.to_bytes(4)[::-1].hex()
```

This is a version of [Joel's Python 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193802/70305) solution that works only on Python 3.11 and higher. Pre-3.11, the `byteorder` argument to `int.to_bytes`/`int.from_bytes` was mandatory; in 3.11 it is now defaulted to `'big'`, so, golf-wise, you can omit it, let `to_bytes` produce the big-endian version, then reverse it with a slice, saving three characters.

(Side-note: The Attempt This Online link actually cheats and just uses Joel's solution when the Python version is below 3.11; ATO is still on 3.10.6 so it can't run this code as of April, 2023)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwRKuNNuYpaUlaboWN5VyEnOTUhIV8qzy9Ery45MqS1KLNUw0o62sdA1j9TJSKzQ0oSqrMnML8otKFIori7ky00CUXllqUXFmfl58Zl5avoKNgoaxjqGhphWXAhCk2WI1WEc9J7OkJCdVXRNiNldBUWZeiUaahpGhiaGphZmJsZEmQtDYwMTczFwT6oIFCyA0AA)