# 8086 Segment Address to Linear

Tags: code-golf, x86-family

Given an 8086 segmented ("*logical*") memory address, output its actual linear physical address.

A segmented memory address has format `xxxx:xxxx`, where each of `x` is one of `0-9A-F`, and the two parts are parsed as hexadecimal integers. Both parts are exactly 4 digits.

To get its actual linear address, multiply the first part by sixteen and add the second part. You can return it in a reasonable format, e.g. integer or a length=5 string. You can choose whether to modulo the result by \$2^{20}\$ (like 8086, or 286+ with the [A20 gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A20_line) closed). Yet input format is fixed.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in each language wins.

Test cases

```
0000:0000 -> 0x00000
1111:1111 -> 0x12221
FFFF:0000 -> 0xFFFF0
FFFF:0010 -> 0x00000 or 0x100000
```

Comment: Is an integer a "reasonable" output format?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes. Added

Comment: What about a base-16 representation like `"1111:1111" -> [4369, 4369]`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan No, input is fixed format

Comment: Yeah, I meant the output format i.e. `[4369, 4368]` is a base 16 representation of the result - just wondering what "reasonable" is and how far we can push it :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan output don't ask for 2 values

Comment: should text output in base 10 be accepted? It's technically the same as any integer, but would be quite unconventional for a memory address

Comment: @ilkkachu I guess so

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes

*-2 thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

Returns an integer.

```javascript
s=>eval(s.replace(/:|^/g,'0+0x'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1i61LDFHo1ivKLUgJzE5VUPfqiZOP11H3UDboEJdU/N/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaSARBYgQglTb2S/OCSosy8dA1DM01NBX19BYMKkIwBF5oeQyCwAhHY9RgaGRkZoutxAwI89oCkDXDoMcTnNoX8IpCVYPZ/AA)

Turns an input such as `"ABCD:1234"` into `"0+0xABCD0+0x1234"` and evaluates it as JS code.

Comment: [33](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1i61LDFHo1ivKLUgJzE5VUPfqiZOP11H3UDboEJdU/N/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaSARBYgQglTb2S/OCSosy8dA1DM01NBX19BYMKkIwBF5oeQyCwAhHY9RgaGRkZoutxAwI89oCkDXDoMcTnNoX8IpCVYPZ/AA)

Comment: @l4m2 Nice one.

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 35 bytes

```
IFS=:;read a b;echo $[16*0x$a+0x$b]
```

Takes input from stdin and outputs to stdout

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8GCpaUlaboWN5U93YJtrayLUhNTFBIVkqxTkzPyFVSiDc20DCpUErWBRFIsRClUx4KVhkBgBSIgAgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 52 bytes

```
main(a,b){scanf("%X:%X",&a,&b);printf("%X",16*a+b);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjdNchMz8zQSdZI0q4uTE_PSNJRUI6xUI5R01BJ11JI0rQuKMvNKwKJKOoZmWonaQLFaiF6oEQtWugGBlYGBoQFEAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## MS-DOS .COM (386 instructions), 71 bytes

Takes input from the command line and prints the result. To convert each output character, I use a variant of [`AAM`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aam) that operates in base 16.

```
BE 82 00 E8 2A 00 8B DF 66 C1 E3 04 46 E8 20 00
66 03 DF 66 C1 CB 10 B9 05 00 8A C3 D4 10 3C 0A
7C 02 04 07 04 30 CD 29 66 C1 C3 04 E2 EC CD 20
66 33 FF B9 04 00 C1 E7 04 AC A8 40 74 02 2C 07
2C 30 03 F8 E2 F0 C3
```

TASM source:

```
IDEAL
P386

MODEL   TINY
CODESEG
ORG 100H

MAIN:
    MOV     SI,82H ; Start of command line
    CALL    DECODE
    MOV     BX,DI
    SHL     EBX,4 ; Adjust segment portion
    INC     SI
    CALL    DECODE
    ADD     EBX,EDI ; Add offset
    ROR     EBX,16 ; Rotate address to point to first digit
    MOV     CX,5
LOOPM:
    MOV     AL,BL
    DB      0D4H, 10H ; AAM 10H (base 16: AH=AL/16, AL=AL mod 16)
    CMP     AL,0AH
    JL      ASCADJ
    ADD     AL,7 ; Convert digits > 9 into A-F
ASCADJ:
    ADD     AL,48
    INT     29H
    ROL     EBX,4 ; Next digit
    LOOP    LOOPM
    INT     20H

DECODE:
    XOR     EDI,EDI ; Return register
    MOV     CX,4
LOOP1:
    SHL     DI,4
    LODSB
    TEST    AL,40H
    JZ      DECADJ
    SUB     AL,7 ; Convert digits A-F to 10-16
DECADJ:
    SUB     AL,48
    ADD     DI,AX
    LOOP    LOOP1
    RET

END MAIN
ENDS
```

Example results:

```
C:\WORK>segment FFFF:0000
FFFF0
```

Comment: There's a slightly more compact trick for generating a hex digit from a 0..15 integer in AL: [Little Endian Number to String Conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193842) - `and al, 0Fh` / `cmp al, 10` / `sbb al, 69h` / `das` (7 bytes), saving 1 vs. aam/cmp/jl/add.

Comment: Does this rely on the high 16 bits of EBX being zeroed?  No, I guess not, you're using a counted loop to only output the set part of BX (not like l4m2's base-10 output loop that goes until zero), and the low 20 bits are known good because of the `shl ebx,4` at one point.  Thanks to the question letting us truncate like the A20 gate, we don't need to support wider linear addresses (`FFFF:00010` and up)

Comment: This and l4m2's could of course be smaller as functions in 32-bit code that return an `int`, but I don't think there's anything particularly interesting about porting the logical-address parsing to that.  (Except that l4m2's clever trick of cmp/je back to a `rol edx,16` before the top of the character loop stays the same size, while two `call` instructions become 5 bytes each instead of 3.)

Comment: `mov al, bl` => `xchg ax, bx` ah bh bl are all trash

Answer (score 4):

## x86 .COM, <s>64</s> 59 bytes

```
0100  BE 82 00 66 31 C9 66 F7-E1 B1 08 66 C1 CA 10 66   ...f1.f....f...f
0110  C1 C2 04 AC 3C 3A 74 F3-2C 30 D4 10 D5 09 66 01   ....<:t.,0....f.
0120  C2 E2 EC 66 92 66 99 B1-0A 66 F7 F1 66 85 C0 52   ...f.f...f..f..R
0130  74 03 E8 F0 FF 58 04 30-CD 29 C3                  t....X.0.).
```

Thank Peter Cordes
for -5 bytes

```
    org $100
    mov si, $82
    xor ecx, ecx
    mul ecx
    mov cl, 8
b:  ror edx, 16
a:  rol edx, 4
    lodsb
    cmp al, ':'
    je b
    sub al, '0'
    aam $10
    aad 9
    add edx, eax
    loop a
    xchg eax, edx
p:  cdq
    mov cl, 10
    div ecx
    test eax, eax
    push dx
    jz q
    call p
q:  pop ax
    add al, '0'
    int $29
    ret
```

Output decimal

Comment: That's not an 8086 program; it requires 386 or higher for 32-bit operand-size (`div ecx`).  That's fine, just make sure to label it appropriately like ErikF's answer (*MS-DOS .COM (386 instructions)*).  The `66h` prefix bytes in the machine code sets the operand-size to the non-default size, i.e. to 32-bit when the CPU's in real mode, but only on 386+.  Also, `ror r/m, imm8` was new in 186: https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insROL, same for `push imm8`.  (But you're only using them with 32-bit operand-size so they of course require 386)

Comment: Seems like there should be a cheaper way to get ECX=10.  `pushd 10` (3 bytes) / `pop ecx` (2 bytes) is 5 total.  `lea ecx, [edx+10]` is also 5 (the normal 3 plus 66h and 67h prefixes).  Oh, you have SI=0x82 + 9, so `lea ecx, [si - 82$ - 9 + 10]` would work, with 16-bit address size.  But `(82$+9)` is just barely too far away from `10`, it needs a disp16: `66 8D 8C  7F FF`.  If you wanted to rely on an initial value of BX, DI, or BP in some DOS versions, that could work, but not be as portable.  [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181407)

Comment: Can we save anything with `xor ecx,ecx` / `mul ecx` to zero 3 registers (including their upper halves) in 6 bytes?  That should allow `mov cl, 8` instead of `mov cx,8`, and `mov cl, 10` instead of `pushd 10` / `pop ecx`.  (After the `loop` instruction, cx = 0, and thus ECX=0).  It also allows optimizing away the `movzx eax, al` (4 bytes), since `aad` leaves AH=0 (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aad) and the upper 16 of EAX are also known zero.

Comment: This requires upper-case hex input, right?  ASCII hex digit to integer via `c-='0';` `(c>>4)*9 + (c&0xf)` would give numbers to large for lower-case ASCII, unlike the `(c>>6)*9 + (c&0xf)` version of the bithack that doesn't subtract first.  That's fine, just seems like it should get mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, `xor ecx, ecx` / `mul ecx` at the start gets it down to 59 bytes, if I didn't break anything.  https://godbolt.org/z/q7Edn9z78

Comment: ` cmp al, ':'
 je b
 jb $+4
 sub al, 7
 sub al, '0'` can make the code without `aam` and `aad` but same size

Answer (score 4):

## Excel (ms365), 37 bytes

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SUM(HEX2DEC(MID(A1,{1,6},4))*{16,1})
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
\:/H16β
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiXFw6L0gxNs6yIiwiIiwiMDAwMDowMDAwXG4xMTExOjExMTFcbkZGRkY6MDAwMFxuRkZGRjowMDEwIl0=)

```
\:/H16β
\:/     # Split on colon
   H    # Convert each from hex string to int
    16β # Convert list from base 16 to decimal
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 39 bytes

```python
lambda x:int(x[:4],16)*16+int(x[5:],16)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY31XMSc5NSEhUqrDLzSjQqoq1MYnUMzTS1DM20IQKmVmABqPLsgiKQcEZqhUaahroBEFiBCHVNTU0uFClDILACEZhSbkCAQxdUyhAsBbFywQIIDQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 31 bytes

```
*+<4+*o{m:g/\w+/».&{:16(~$_)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfS9vGRFsrvzrXKl0/plxb/9BuPbVqK0MzjTqVeM3a2v/FiZUKSirxCrZ2CtVpGkAxvaTE4lQNQzPNWiWFtPwiBRsDILACEQqGQGAFIhTcgAAiBmUZGtj9BwA)

This is two anonymous functions composed together with the `o` operator.  The first, `* +< 4 + *` returns its first argument shifted left four bits (ie, multiplied by 16) plus its second argument.  The second, enclosed by braces, extracts the two hexadecimal substrings (`m:g/\w+/`) and parses them into integers (`:16(~$_)`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
q': ÔËnG *GpE
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=cSc6INTLbkcgKkdwRQ&input=IkZGRkY6MDAwMCI)

Output is an integer. [This](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=cSc6INTLbkcgKkdwRQ&footer=IjB4IitVeCBzRyB1&input=IkZGRkY6MDAwMCI) version includes a footer which translates to the format in the test cases (No modulus, so it outputs `0x100000` for the last test case).

Explanation:

```
q': ÔËnG *GpE
q':           # Split input where the character ':' appears
    Ô         # Reverse the array
     Ë        # Map:
      nG      #  Treat the string as a base-16 number
         *    #  Multiply with
          GpE #  16 to the power of the current index

-x            # Output the sum of the resulting array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 35 bytes

```factor
[ ":"split1 hex> swap hex> 16 * + ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCsIwFEV3v@LSUaE0i0MER8XFRZzEIZSnLbZp8vIkivjtMW09w@FylnsztQyczqfDca8RXNeKtPaO3khTOsOBGA9iS92U4JhE3o5bK/ARgfyTbE0Bm4WPH1QZPQoqo0dhl5nbf6kK33RBoYvpT6Gh1xYhGjcvtcYSK1xTn0uZfg)

```
       ! "1111:1111"
":"    ! "1111:1111" ":"
split1 ! "1111" "1111"
hex>   ! "1111" 4369
swap   ! 4369 "1111"
hex>   ! 4369 4369
16     ! 4369 4369 16
*      ! 4369 69904
+      ! 74273
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 53 bytes

```python
lambda x:int((s:=x.split(':'))[0],16)*16+int(s[1],16)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3TXMSc5NSEhUqrDLzSjQ0iq1sK_SKC3IySzTUrdQ1NaMNYnUMzTS1DM20QfLF0YZgPlRzdkERSDQjtUIjTUPdAAisQARQnyYXipQhEFiBCEwpNyDAoQsqZQiWgli5YAGEBgA)

Returns an integer (ok as per OP). Footer on ATO converts to hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>13</s>  11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

<sup>Jelly has no built-in standard hex string conversion functions :/</sup>

```
ØHiⱮ’ṣ-ḅ⁴ḅ⁴
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of characters (as defined) and yields an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDI/MRxvXPWqY@XDnYt2HO1ofNW6BkP///1c3BAIrEKEOAA)**

#### How?

```
ØHiⱮ’ṣ-ḅ⁴ḅ⁴ - Link: list of characters, S
ØH         - hex-characters -> "0123456789ABCDEF"
   Ɱ       - map across c in S with:
  i        -   first 1-indexed index of c in the hex-characters or 0
    ’      - decrement (vectorises)
      -    - literal -1
     ṣ     - split the ØHiⱮ’ result at -1's (this is what ':' will have mapped to)
       ḅ⁴   - convert from base sixteen (vectorises)
         ḅ⁴ - convert from base sixteen
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org) `-aF:`, 29 + 4 = 33 bytes

```
print 16*hex($F[0])+hex $F[1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kILUoZ0W0km6im5VS7IKlpSVpuhZ7C4oy80oUDM20MlIrNFTcog1iNbWBTAUg0zAWogaqdMFKQyCwAhEQAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
⍘↨Ｅ⪪Ｓ:⍘ι⊗⁸⊗⁸⊗⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITAczNXwTCzSCC3IySzQ88wpKS6BSmjoKSlZKQBJJeaaOgkt@aVJOaoqGhaamJgoPVcr6/38zILACEf91y3IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    Ｓ           Input string
   ⪪            Split on
     :          Literal string `:`
  Ｅ             Map over parts
       ι        Current part
      ⍘         Convert from base
         ⁸      Literal integer `8`
        ⊗       Doubled
 ↨              Convert from base
           ⁸    Literal integer `8`
          ⊗     Doubled
⍘               Convert to base
             ⁸  Literal integer `8`
            ⊗   Doubled
                Implicitly print
```

Consecutive integers would require a separator so I double `8` instead of using a literal `16`. (The first one doesn't need to be double `8` but I wanted to be consistent.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 87 bytes

```
:
0¶0
O#$`.
$.%`
¶

M!`..
[a-f]
55$&
T`l`d
.
$*
+`¶1{16}
1¶
1{16}

%M`1
T`d`l`..
b\B|¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYsxCgIxEEX7fwsxEVkxZJCsmNLGarGxU2F2iQFBthA79Vo5QC4WJ6yv@Hz@vHneXvexL3p54OJhc7I4zhUbKKMZOQHdjI3BuV/HK5xTC5z4wQFiNFhxTvSm9gsSdWrQHZNIQTR5HC77j9xKsYKvARJ8DURh2v6NLFrB1wC5XfCb7RB/) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
:
0¶0
```

Replace the separator with a newline, but also suffixing a `0` to the first number and prefixing a `0` to the second number, reducing the problem to hexadecimal addition.

```
O#$`.
$.%`
¶

M!`..
```

Transpose the digits.

```
[a-f]
55$&
T`l`d
.
$*
```

Convert each digit to unary. As they are now transposed, each line now corresponds to the sum of the two digits in unary.

```
+`¶1{16}
1¶
1{16}
```

Propagate carries, but drop the 20th carry (allowed per spec).

```
%M`1
```

Convert each resulting "digit" to decimal.

```
T`d`l`..
b\B|¶
```

Convert each decimal number to a hexadecimal digit and join everything together.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 23 bytes

```
Uo{aFB16*16E Do}MSa^":"
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCJGIGEgW1xuW1wiMDAwMDowMDAwXCJdO1xuW1wiMTExMToxMTExXCJdO1xuW1wiRkZGRjowMDAwXCJdO1xuW1wiRkZGRjowMDEwXCJdXG5de1dHIFAoe1xuICIsIlVve2FGQjE2KjE2RSBEb31NU2FeXCI6XCIiLCJ9VmEpVEIxNlxufSIsIiIsIi1wIl0=)

I couldn't quite figure out a nice way to multiply the first part by 16, I'm sure @DLosc will be able to save the day

Comment: Can you shift bits in Pip?

Comment: @jdt not that I know of

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 40 bytes

```c
i;f(s){sscanf(s,"%x:%x",&i,&s);s+=i<<4;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7RCsIgGIXv9xQiOLQ5cNDV3G57hqB2IZL1Q1nMQYOxV890WzXou/g9fBzh6PystfcgDXVscE4rGxLHpC9Jj3kKPHVMuqyGqtrK0YPt0E2BpSwZEhTQF9VuUHdy3aFBNZplBItAGQ/mP1kEynjWchf4ay6yWEsxpVFOj7m3iMY9UAs5L4BGIsgy9v3waEPBUExc2CZ6sj9azD9djgxdImMyGf1Lm6s6O58/3w)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>44</s> 36 bytes

```
strtoi(scan(,"",,,":"),16)%*%c(16,1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWN1WKS4pK8jM1ipMT8zR0lJR0dHSUrJQ0dQzNNFW1VJM1DM10DDUham8xphsAgRWI4OKC6lMyqADxDZQ0uZSJB1zE2MplCARWIALZNkMjIyNDWtjmBgQYfgMJ0sRvUNsMUWwzhAYlJLxhcQQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 7 bytes (14 nibbles)

```
`@4.`=$\$Nhex
```

Outputs decimal address value.

```
`@4.`=$\$Nhex
    `=$         # chunk the input by
       \$       # its character class:
         N      #   is it alphanumeric?
   .            # now map over the 3 chunks
                # (the middle one is ":")
          hex   #   get hex value
                #   (value of ":" is zero)
`@4             # and convert the 3-element list
                # to base-4
```

[image]

---

For the same bytes, we could also explicitly split `%` the input on the string `":"`, and convert from base-16, similarly to some other answers:
 `` `@16.%$":"hex ``

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>83</s> 80 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func f(s string)int{l,r:=0,0
Sscanf(s,"%x:%x",&l,&r)
return l*16+r}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU_BasQgFLz7FSJkia1dNNBShL32vNBj24OEGKSJCWpACPslvYSFvfUn-hn7N31vE9o5vMHRN-N8ndth-R5N_WnahvbG-cuU7MPz9ej6cQhpz2yfGLGTr6ktI40pON9y59PciaAPUkjyGmvj4VKwIusiM7HrxC5wEpo0BU-7O_V0H06b78_NCoNKTmdSm9hEqg-gjG-r-QeaEyYBGgfTMiNLQZgCaBwoqqqqFIgvgL-XeJD_orqJats_ETsEGoXDxGA8VF4_MJMjRCdbsiJSmQv5mDd690zghoCCnIPDVmRZVv4F)

Very similar to the other answers with some sort of `Scanf`: Look for 2 hex numbers, put them into variables, and return the result.

- -3 bytes from @Steffan: `var l,r int => l,r:=0,0`

Comment: `l,r:=0,0` is shorter than `var l,r int`

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
':¡H16β
```

Outputs as an integer.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f3erQQg9Ds3Ob/v93AwIrAwNDAwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/datDCz0Mzc5t@u9in6GkoGFQcXi/ppLO/2glAyCwAhFKOkqGQGAFIoBsNyCAiUPZhgZKsQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
':¡     '# Split the (implicit) input-string on ":"
   H     # Convert both strings in the pair from hexadecimal to base-10 integers
    16β  # Convert this list to a base-16 integer
         # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 44 bytes

```arturo
$[s][+*16from.hex take s 4from.hex drop s 5]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?yvmCST)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](//docs.python.org/3.8), 42 bytes

Python translation of [@Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s JavaScript solution

```
lambda a:eval('0x'+a.replace(':','0+0x'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSHRKrUsMUdD3aBCXTtRryi1ICcxOVVD3UpdR0HdQBsoqqn5v6AoM69EIw2oCAisQARQlAsuaggEViACRTQNCDDVQkUNQaL/AQ)