# Power-Ending Patterns

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, integer

When you look at the last decimal digit of each power of a non-negative integer a repeating pattern forms. For example, 3:

```
3^1 =     3
3^2 =     9
3^3 =    27
3^4 =    81
3^5 =   243
3^6 =   729
3^7 =  2187
3^8 =  6561
3^9 = 19683
```

The last digits go `3971` which repeats indefinitely. In fact any number we choose that ends in 3 has that same pattern because none of the other digits can have an effect on the ones place during repeated multiplication.

What's curious is that some numbers have a much shorter cycle of power-ending digits. For example with 5 the powers all end in 5 so the pattern, written as short as possible, is simply `5`.

Looking at the minimal power-ending digits patterns for 0 through 9 we get:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 2486
3 -> 3971
4 -> 46
5 -> 5
6 -> 6
7 -> 7931
8 -> 8426
9 -> 91
```

(The lengths of these being `11442` repeated is a curious tidbit itself.)

Remember, any numbers above 9 will have the same pattern as their last digit as was explained above with 3.

## Challenge

Your challenge here is to write a program that takes in any non-negative integer and outputs its minimal power-ending digit pattern.

The exact output formatting, whether string or list, doesn't matter. For example, here are some potential inputs followed by valid potential outputs:

```
900 -> [0]
11 -> 1
2 -> 2486
303 -> 3, 9, 7, 1
44 -> 4 6
45 -> 5
666 -> "6"
3857 -> [7 9 3 1]
118 -> '8426'
129 -> [9, 1]
```

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: I assume we can't indefinitely print the list?

Comment: @RGS No. The point is to just print the minimal sequence of 1, 2, or 4 digits.

Comment: "Your challenge here is to write a program **that takes in any non-negative integer** and outputs it's minimal power-ending digit pattern" but then "Pretty much **reproduce the list above**." & [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] - which is it?

Comment: ...I guess the former since you give examples, I suggest removing the KC tag and "Pretty much reproduce the list above."

Comment: @JonathanAllan I figured there could be elements of KC in some solutions since the data is pretty small. And for the inputs 0 to 9 the list would be reproduced. Sorry if that's not clear - I'm open to better phrasing?

Comment: If we want to put this in the math jargon, this is the semigroup generated by \$n\$ on the monoid \$\langle\mathbb{Z}_{10},\times\rangle\$.

Comment: Are we allowed to produce incorrect results upon overflow?

Comment: @S.S.Anne Like if the input integer is too big? That's fine. As long as your program can accept integers up to your language's usual maximum, like 2^31-1.

Comment: No, if the calculations of the integers inside the functions are too big.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Ah. Good point. It's ok if things overflow if you're taking powers.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies: compactly encoding a lookup table can be *part* of a code-golf answer.  That doesn't mean the overall problem is one of Kolmogorov complexity.  It's nice that the question points out that the pattern for any number is the pattern for it's lowest decimal digit.  Maybe you want to replace some of the other phrasing with that?  But @ JonathanAllen already told you how to fix the biggest misleading part: simply remove the sentence "Pretty much reproduce the list above."  The test cases are clearer *without* that.

Comment: @640KB Nope, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 40 bytes

Based off of [mabel's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198817/75323) but using dictionary comprehensions:

```
lambda n:[*{n**i%10:0for i in[1,2,3,4]}]
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to mabel.

Saved 3 bytes thanks to xnor.

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIc8qWqs6T0srU9XQwMogLb9IIVMhMy/aUMdIx1jHJLY29j9ILA8oplCUmJeeqmFoYqZpxaUABAVFmXklGmlK1Xm1Crp2CtVpGnmatUqa/wE)

Comment: ah of course! I forgot about these

Comment: you can replace `:i for` with `:1for` to save a byte

Comment: @mabel clever trick!

Comment: Python 3's list unpacking can save a few bytes: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIc8qWqs6T0srU9XQwMogLb9IIVMhMy/aUMdIx1jHJLY29j9ILA8oplCUmJeeqmFoYqZpxaUABAVFmXklGmlK1Xm1Crp2CtVpGnmatUqa/wE

Comment: Ah I knew it was possible @xnor but I couldn't remember what it was called, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
*Ɱ4%⁵Q
```

A monadic link which accepts an integer and yield a list of integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/r0cZ1JqqPGrcG/v//39DIEgA)**

#### How?

```
*Ɱ4%⁵Q - Link: integer, n
  4    - four
 Ɱ     - map across (implicit range of [1..4]) with:
*      -    exponentiate
    ⁵  - ten
   %   - (powers) mod (ten)
     Q - de-duplicate
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 41 bytes

```javascript
n=>[n%=10]+[[,,486,971,6,,,931,426,1][n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc9BDsIgEIXhvadgY9LG0TJAKSzqRQiLprbGpgFjjddHktnB@sufmbdNv@mYP6/39xriY0nrmMJ4d@E8IvcX5wCU0WAHBA0AViIooQG9C96nOYYj7sttj89mbZjlvG1Z1zF@KoQhkmAlTJCIfKdEySWhzA9UpVKEStfUE/WlaK1JykaafiAZ8sgyQzSEJq@vUFhCi@kP)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes

A recursive version.

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>(d=(k*n)%10)-n?[k]+g(d):k)(n%=10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc1NDsIgFATgvadg0wQ0tTygFEzQgxgXTf@iNGCs8frY5O1gM4v5MplX/@u34fN8f@sQxynNLgV3pYvze46O@mNgFXBWh9vdP04LHdnFMxoqt5dpiGGL63Re40JnSiznjJGmIfyQCQFAgUKIQBHK6Bwll4jSduVSKUSlS2qR2ly01ij5Rpq2Q@msLL4ADKJRongDYREtpD8)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

```python
lambda n:list(dict.fromkeys(n**i%10for i in(1,2,3,4)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcrBCoMwDADQXwmCkEgZVj0JfonzUKfRME2l9iLit3envfM7rrh6rRNDB@@0uX2cHGi7yRlxkk98cfD7d75O1KKQ3JbsAwiIojWVqU1DRKk/gmhEzm55WrgZhZ6M4F8hOF1mtCUN6Qc)

Could have been 38 bytes if `set()` was ordered.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

Jo King suggested a shorter function than what I originally had, `∪10⊤*∘⍳∘4` (a train at 9 bytes) vs my 10-byter dfn, and ngn pointed out a tradfn would be shorter than both altogether

```apl
∪10⊤⎕*⍳4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9DUisMjSoedQ3VetR72YTkNj/NC5DYyMA)

`⍳4` the vector 1 2 3 4

`⎕*` the input raised to the power of, i.e. `(⍵*1)(⍵*2)(⍵*3)(⍵*4)` (using `⍵` to represent the value of the input)

`10⊤` mod 10

`∪` unique

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEcdqwwNHnUt0XrUMeNR72YgafL//6PeVRqPuhbpgMS6mtI0D60AShkaGAAA)

Comment: @JoKing `*∘⍳∘4` -> `⎕*⍳4` to make it a "full program"

Comment: Thanks, to both of you.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <strike>7</strike> 6 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

```
4LmT%Ù
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxCc3RPXwzP//DY0sAQ)

Just a port of [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198811/91097).

Comment: You can remove the `€`, since it's done implicitly.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that @KevinCruijssen

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
4:^10\u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38QqztAgpvT/f2MLU3MA)

#### Explanation

```
4:    % Push [1 2 3 4]
^     % Implicit input, n. Element-wise power: gives [n n^2 n^3 n^4]
10\   % Modulo 10
u     % Unique (remove duplicates). Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>48</s> 46 bytes

`` import Data.List;f n=nub[n^i`mod`10|i<-[1..4]] ``

-2 bytes thanks to @Laikoni

Having to import `nub` is really annoying... Any suggestions to remove it?

You can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuIQrTSHPNq80KTovLjMhNz8lwdCgJtNGN9pQT88kNvZ/bmJmnoKtQkFpSXBJkYKKQnFGfjmQyk0sUEhTACkyMoj9/x8A)

Comment: Here's a version without `nub`, but it is also 48 bytes: ```n!i|x<-n^i`mod`10=x:[y|i<4,y<-n!(i+1),y/=x];(!1)``` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfbqsQ819D0VCTK08xs6bCRjcvLjMhNz8lwdDAtsIqurIm08ZEpxIorKiRqW2oqVOpb1sR@z83MTNPwVahoCgzr0RBRSE3sUAhXSHaUE/PyCD2//9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: However, your version can be shortened to 46 bytes: ```import Data.List;f n=nub[n^i`mod`10|i<-[1..4]]``` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuIQrTSHPNq80KTovLjMhNz8lwdCgJtNGN9pQT88kNvZ/bmJmnoKtQkFpSXBJkYKKQnFGfjmQyk0sUEhTACkyMoj9/x8A "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Laikoni thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 42 bytes

```javascript
n=>new Set([1,2,3,4].map(v=>(n%10)**v%10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc1NDoIwFATgvafoxqQQhL7@0S7gEi6NC4LFaLAlQvD4VfN27WqS@TKZ57AP6/h@LNvJh5uLUxd913v3IWe30QtUvBKVvNavYaF711N/BFaU5f6PIo7Br2F29RzudKLEsl9JmoawQyIEAAUyIRyFS6NTFEwgCtvmSykRpc5JIalUtNYo6UYY1aK0VmRfAAbRSJ69AbeIFuIX)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

This solution is suggested by @Expired Data, it is shorter, elegant but it will have problems when working with large number.

```javascript
n=>new Set([1,2,3,4].map(v=>n**v%10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc29DoIwGIXh3avoYlIIQr/@0Q54E47GgWAxGGyJELz8SvJt7XqenLzvfu/X4Tst28WHp4tjF3139e5Hbm6jd6h4JSr5qD/9QvcDynI/AyuKOAS/htnVc3jRkRLLjpE0DWGnRAgACmRCOAqXRqcomEAUts2fUiJKnZNCUqlorVHSjzCqRWmtyFoABtFIntWAW0QL8Q8)

Comment: [do you need to take n modulo 10?](https://tio.run/##Zc29DoIwGIXh3avoYlIIQr/@0Q54E47GgWAxGGyJELz8SvJt7XqenLzvfu/X4Tst28WHp4tjF3139e5Hbm6jd6h4JSr5qD/9QvcDynI/AyuKOAS/htnVc3jRkRLLjpE0DWGnRAgACmRCOAqXRqcomEAUts2fUiJKnZNCUqlorVHSjzCqRWmtyFoABtFIntWAW0QL8Q8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Expired Data thank for your solution, I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, 26 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: b380 8a07 d72c 308a d850 0430 b40e cd10  .....,0..P.0....
00000010: 58f6 e3d4 0a3a c375 f0c3                 X....:.u..
```

**Unassembled:**

```
B3 80       MOV  BL, 80H            ; BX to command line input tail
8A 07       MOV  AL, BYTE PTR[BX]   ; input length into AL 
D7          XLAT                    ; AL = [BX+AL] (get the last char of input) 
2C 30       SUB  AL, '0'            ; convert from ASCII
8A D8       MOV  BL, AL             ; save N to BL for compare/multiply
        POW_LOOP: 
50          PUSH AX                 ; save AX 
04 30       ADD  AL, '0'            ; convert to ASCII 
B4 0E       MOV  AH, 0EH            ; BIOS tty function 
CD 10       INT  10H                ; call BIOS, write char to console 
58          POP  AX                 ; restore AX 
F6 E3       MUL  BL                 ; AX = AL * BL 
D4 0A       AAM                     ; AL = AL % 10 
3A C3       CMP  AL, BL             ; is sequence repeating? 
75 F0       JNE  POW_LOOP           ; if not, keep looping 
C3          RET                     ; return to DOS
```

A standalone PC DOS executable program.  Input via command line args.

**I/O:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>54</del> 50 bytes

```php
for($n=$o=$argn%10;print$n;$n-$o||die)$n=$n*$o%10;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFTybFXybVUSi9LzVA0NrAuKMvNKVPKsVfJ0VfJralIyUzVBKvK0VPJB0v//m5iaGf3LLyjJzM8r/q/rBgA)

---

Alternate Solution:

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>50</del> 45 bytes

```php
for(;$i<'11442'[$argn%5];)echo$argn**++$i%10;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoPA/Lb9Iw1ol00bd0NDExEg9WiWxKD1P1TTWWjM1OSMfzNPS0tZWyVQ1NLD@/9/Y@F9@QUlmfl7xf103AA)

Answer (score 1):

## x86_64 machine code, <s>63</s> 61 bytes

```
B8 BF 84 7B 09 B9 0A 00 00 00 31 D2 C7 44 24 FC
A4 10 0A 00 48 C1 E0 22 48 89 44 24 EC 48 B8 3C
00 00 00 00 00 5E 24 48 89 44 24 F4 89 F8 66 F7
F1 48 89 D0 83 E0 0F 66 03 54 44 EC C3
```

Disassembly:

```
00000000  B8BF847B09        mov eax,0x97b84bf
00000005  B90A000000        mov ecx,0xa
0000000A  31D2              xor edx,edx
0000000C  C74424FCA4100A00  mov dword [rsp-0x4],0xa10a4
00000014  48C1E022          shl rax,byte 0x22
00000018  48894424EC        mov [rsp-0x14],rax
0000001D  48B83C0000000000  mov rax,0x245e00000000003c
         -5E24
00000027  48894424F4        mov [rsp-0xc],rax
0000002C  89F8              mov eax,edi
0000002E  66F7F1            div cx
00000031  4889D0            mov rax,rdx
00000034  83E00F            and eax,byte +0xf
00000037  66035444EC        add dx,[rsp+rax*2-0x14]
0000003C  C3                ret
```

Input: `edi`, Output: `dx`, requires `rsp` to be set to a correct value.

Example call:

```
main:
  mov edi, 1337
  call f
  movzx eax, dx
  ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>58</s> 50 bytes

```
.*(.)
$1$1$*_,,486,971,6,,,931,426,1
+`_\d*,

,.*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcFLDkAwFAXQ@V0HSdVN41WVrsAmJEgYmBiI/dffOdu8L@sYU9UO0WhlMiRy1j3pGs9QCz3JUAqd9RTkQ99NmgCNRowFRGCtRXmCu6C6wT9Qv9B8EH4H) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 8 bytes by not including the input digit in the digit patterns. Explanation:

```
.*(.)
$1$1$*_,,486,971,6,,,931,426,1
```

Create a unary copy of the last digit and append the list of power-ending digit pattern suffixes.

```
+`_\d+,
```

Delete the appropriate number of entries from the start of the list.

```
,.*
```

Delete unneeded entries from the end of the list.

Actually calculating the digits takes 69 bytes:

```
M!`.$
{`(.).*
$&;$1$*_,$&$*
_(?=.*,(1*))|,1*
$1
;(1{10})*(1*)
$.2
D`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcm7DoJAEEbh/n8Lk4HMTjYTZgWUEGNjYsUzsBQWNBaGDnz2Fbx95TmP2zTeh5TxNaZuF5UwR1anAspbMpLeU06Cns8nFc8mzi3e1m1o2WYrnk62CtKAS9SUCpghhID9CuUG1RvqDxy@cPxB8/cC) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
M!`.$
```

Modulo the input by 10.

```
{`
```

Repeat while new digits can be added.

```
(.).*
$&;$1$*_,$&$*
```

Create unary copies of the first digit and power-ending digits so far.

```
_(?=.*,(1*))|,1*
$1
```

Multiply them together.

```
;(1{10})*(1*)
$.2
```

Take the remainder modulo 10 and convert it to decimal.

```
D`.
```

Deduplicate the digits.

Of course it only takes 34 bytes in Retina 1:

```
L`.$
{`(.).*
$&_$.(*$1*
_.*\B

D`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcG7DkBAEAXQ/n7HkjXFxKx3KxKNT5BYhUKjEJ2PH2/nrNM2L6NoYFuvnWeD3VuOmGDCwbAlI4SBqa@BxrNqDBE455CckF6Q3ZA/ULxQflD9Dg) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
L`.$
```

Modulo the input by 10.

```
{`
```

Repeat while new digits can be added.

```
(.).*
$&_$.(*$1*
```

Multiply the power-ending pattern so far by its first digit. (`*` has higher precedence than `$^`, so multiplying by its reverse ends up costing a byte more than it saves.)

```
_.*\B
```

Modulo the result by 10.

```
D`.
```

Deduplicate the digits.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 23 bytes

```perl6
((*X**1..4)X%10).unique
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfQ0MrQkvLUE/PRDNC1dBAU680L7OwNPW/NVdxYqWCHlBNWn6RAlDe8j8A)

Returns the unique values of the input to the power of 1 through 4 modulo 10.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 53 bytes

```
=CHOOSE(RIGHT(A1)+1,,1,2486,3971,46,5,6,7931,8426,91)
```

`RIGHT(A1)` defaults to `RIGHT(A1,1)`, making it more efficient than `MOD(A1,10)`

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
4╒#♂%▀
```

port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198811/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/k0dRJyo9mNqk@mtbw/7@lgQGXoSGXEZexgTGXiQmXiSmXmZkZl7GFqTlQ3ILL0MgSAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
4╒      # Push the list [1,2,3,4]
  #     # Take the (implicit) input-integer to each of this power
   ♂%   # Take modulo-10 for each of these
     ▀  # Uniquify the list
        # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>56</s></sup> 51 bytes

Saved 5 bytes thanks to [S.S. Anne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89298/s-s-anne)!!!

```c
i;f(n){for(i=n%10;putchar(i+48),i=n*i%10,i-n%10;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBCoMwEETv@YpgKWwaLbb0UIj2S3qRtakL7So2QkDy7enqZYZ5MwxWb8ScyXlgs/pxBmr5eKndtAQcOon2djelwBMJLqnaW@NSPhDjZ@lfuvmFnsbz8FDfjhjMqvR@xEHHtnY6NldRa@PWaA/ROPFploGH4snFlpNK@Q8)

Comment: Wow. I feel ashamed now...

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYzBCoMwEETv@YpgKWwaLbb0UIj2S3qRtakL7So2QkDy7enqZYZ5MwxWb8ScyXlgs/pxBmr5eKndtAQcOon2djelwBMJLqnaW@NSPhDjZ@lfuvmFnsbz8FDfjhjMqvR@xEHHtnY6NldRa@PWaA/ROPFploGH4snFlpNK@Q8)

Comment: @S.S.Anne Nice one, was thinking a `for` loop might golf some bytes but hadn't figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168932/89298

Comment: @S.S.Anne Interesting, makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..4).map{|g|n**g%10}|[]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNQT89EUy83saC6Jr0mT0srXdXQoLYmOrb2v6GBXklmbmpxdU1RTYFCdJFOWnRRLFAcAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
{m%^QdTS4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzpXNS4wJSTY5P9/43/5BSWZ@XnF/3VTAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Jelly, 7 bytes

```
4R*@%⁵Q
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98kSMtB9VHj1sD///8bmhgBAA). [It doesn't beat Jonathan's answer nor was it posted first. I just got to this answer by myself and I like posting Jelly answers while I'm learning]

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
⭆⁺0§⪪”←‴Ki⦃k‽” Ｉθ﹪⁺ＩθＩιχ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaATklBZrKBko6Sg4lnjmpaRWaAQX5GSWaCgpKBiZmSiYmVgoGAEllRSUNHUUnBOLSzQKNTWBTN/8lNKcfIh2qDBUPhMkbWgAVGX9/7@FxX/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses the repetition between the first and second halves of the table. Explanation:

```
     ”←‴Ki⦃k‽”              Compressed string `  264 648 2`
    ⪪                       Split on literal space
   §           Ｉθ           Cyclically index by the input as a number
 ⁺0                         Prefix a literal `0`
⭆                           Map over characters and join
                 ﹪⁺ＩθＩιχ    Add to the input and reduce modulo 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 116 bytes

```c
x,c,a[4];f(n){n%=10;for(c=0,x=n;c<4;x*=n)a[c++]=x%10;n=*a*10+a[1];n=a[2]*10+a[3]-n?n*100+a[2]*10+a[3]:*a-a[1]?n:*a;}
```

Can almost certainly be golfed more but I haven't figured it out yet.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7NDoIwEITvfYoGQ9IfMEU5WSoPUntoimgTXQyiaUJ4dmz14FxmZuc7rCsvzq1rKFxhdW1kT4DOkKtKyH4YiVOiCAqka2oZmAJqtePcqJBHABSzrBLc6srEYvXO/OrelNBCzKn8jwdmy8S2EJNc1o0Hd3t1Z9w8p84P2@sRIQ8TvlsP5D34jqIZ4aj0SRoCVljIaA2uknNOv3vSY4xET7K8O0FW4J4ESiVa1g8)

Comment: Can you drop `n%=10;`?

Comment: @JonathanFrech No. For larger integers omitting that will cause overflow.

Comment: Most of the time such overflow deviations are acceptable; one may need to ask the OP for clarification.

Comment: Suggest `x=n%=10;for(c=0;` instead of `n%=10;for(c=0,x=n;`

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 bytes

```
[:~.10|]^1+i.@4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o63q9AwNamLjDLUz9RxM/mtyKXClJmfkK6QpqOnZKWQCJf8DAA)

## [K (Kona)](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 14 bytes

```
{?(x^1+!4)!10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNzs9L/P8/zaraXqMizlBb0URT0dCg9n@aOpD6DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 12 bytes

```
ri4ro?^)[~NB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/KNOkKN8@TjO6zs/p/39DQ0MA)

```
ri   # Read input to int
4ro  # Range [1,4]
?^   # Raise input to powers [1,4]
)[~  # Take last digit of each
NB   # Remove duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
UQ(a**\,4)%t
```

takes range from 1 to 4, takes powers, mod 10, uniquify.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/NFAjUUsrRsdEU7Xk////xgbGAA)