# Circular chained compound

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

## Task

Given a positive integer `n`, output the joined compound of circles

The circles are of square of size `n+2` but removing the corner edges and the middle, before finally overlapping `n` times of itself

E.g.

```
2
```

->

```
####
####
####
####
```

->

```
 ##
#  #
#  #
 ##
```

->

```
 ## ##
#  #  #
#  #  #
 ## ##
```

## Testcases

```
1
->
 #
# #
 #

2
->
 ## ##
#  #  #
#  #  #
 ## ##


3
->
 ### ### ###
#   #   #   #
#   #   #   #
#   #   #   #
 ### ### ###


4
->
 #### #### #### ####
#    #    #    #    #
#    #    #    #    #
#    #    #    #    #
#    #    #    #    #
 #### #### #### ####
```

Trailing spaces are allowed

You have to use the character `#`

You have to join the strings by newlines (no lists)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'#úR×Ćи¬DÙÂ‡.ø»
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//ycjw7pSw5fEhtC4wqxEw5nDguKAoS7DuMK7//80) or [verify the first 5 results](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/qquSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkX1oC4en4HZ7wX1358K6gw9OPtF3YcWiNy@GZh5seNSzUO7zj0O7/Ooe22f8HAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
'#             '# Push "#"
  ú             # Pad it with the (implicit) input amount of leading spaces
   R            # Reverse it so the spaces are trailing
    ×           # Repeat this the (implicit) input amount of times as string
     Ć          # Enclose; append its own head (the "#")
      и         # Repeat it the (implicit) input amount of times as list
       ¬        # Push its first item (without popping the list)
        D       # Duplicate it
         Ù      # Uniquify its characters: "# "
          Â     # Bifurcate; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy: " #"
           ‡    # Transliterate all "# " to " #" in the duplicated string
            .ø  # Surround the list with this string as leading/trailing item
              » # Join by newlines
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

I initially tried to use the Canvas builtin, but [it ended up at twice the amount of bytes..](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6FHDLItHHb0uxnqHFh9a7WloqGWse2glUERd2fzwXBO9eGOfQ6sPrQMKnJv9/78JAA)

Answer (score 11):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>37 32 31 30</sup> 28 bytes

```
'# '{~(>:+*:)($=/~0,~])0,#&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1ZUV1KvrNOystLWsNDVUbPXrDHTqYjUNdJTVDP9rcqUmZ@QrpCkYQxjq6jABI3QBw/8A)

*-2 thanks to ovs for realizing XOR could be replaced with XNOR*

### key idea

The 2d pattern we seek is just the XOR function table of these two 1d patterns:

```
   0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
  --------------------------
0 |0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
1 |1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
1 |1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 <-- XOR TABLE                 
1 |1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
0 |0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: I had that idea too! Those two patterns are the divisibilities of range(n*n+1) and range(n+1) by n+1.

Comment: @emanresuA Yeah, I actually tried to approach building them that way first, but the approach I took ended up being golfier in J.

Comment: *XNOR* is 2 bytes short in J

Answer (score 6):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 86 bytes

```lua
x,a,c=...," ","\n"b=a.rep;d=b(a..b("#",x),x)print(d..c..b(b("#"..b(a,x),x+1)..c,x)..d)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704pzRxwYKlpSVpuhY3wyp0EnWSbfX09HSUFJR0lGLylJJsE_WKUgusU2yTNBL19JI0lJSVdCo0gaigKDOvRCNFTy8ZJAyWADESwbLahppACSBTTy9FE2I61JIl0YYGsVA2AA) Tried moving some stuff around but couldn't get an improvement.

[image: ATO with x=4. trailing newline is part of ATO]

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! Nice first answer. Hope you enjoy your time here!

Answer (score 6):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <sup>37 35 34 30</sup> 26 bytes

```
{"# "(1,s)=\:1,/x#,s:&x,1}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6pWUlZQ0jDUKda0jbEy1NGvUNYptlKr0DGs5eJKUzDmAgCPZAfm)

Yay my second k answer!

Uses @Jonah's approach.

*¯2 bytes thanks to @doug in the k tree*

*¯1 bytes by using `@`*

*¯4 bytes thanks to @ovs and @doug*

*¯4 bytes thanks to @Traws*

Comment: I believe function application and indexing are the same thing, so the `@` is not needed. And to make a table one of the *each's* is enough, as `=` already vectorizes.

Comment: you can rearrage the expression and use `1,&x` instead of `~!1+x` to save a [few](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#eJxLs6pWUlZQ0jDUKda0jbEy1NGvUNYptlKr0DGs5eJKUzDmAgCPZAfm) bytes

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `C`, 16 bytes

```
v\#₌≬₅*Ṅ꘍R₅*ǏȮJJ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJDIiwiIiwidlxcI+KCjOKJrOKChSrhuYTqmI1S4oKFKsePyK5KSiIsIiIsIjMiXQ==)

(IMO) this is some pretty elegant code. It uses some quite neat tricks to achieve the score it is. The output format's still stupid though.

```
v\#              # Fill 1..n with spaces
   ₌-----        # Apply both to the stack...
    ≬---         # The next three elements as one
     ₅*Ṅ         # Repeat each by its length and join with spaces
        ꘍        # And prepend n spaces to each #
         R       # Reverse each of those so a # is at the start
          ₅*     # Repeat each of those by the required length
            Ǐ    # Append the first character (#)
             Ȯ   # Push the item under (the #  #  #) to the stack
              JJ # Append that and prepend it
                 # (C flag) join by newlines and centre
```

An approach similar to Jonas' answer, but independently derived:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 18 bytes

```
›D?*"ʀ$Ḋƒv꘍ƛ‛ #$İ∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwi4oC6RD8qXCLKgCThuIrGknbqmI3Gm+KAmyAjJMSw4oiRIiwiIiwiMyJd)

The last 7 bytes exist because of the stupid output format, and some Vyxal bugs.

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `joe`, 18 bytes

```
v\#*Ṅðp…£v\#?꘍*Ǐ¥J
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqb2UiLCIiLCJ2XFwjKuG5hMOwcOKApsKjdlxcIz/qmI0qx4/CpUoiLCIiLCIzIl0=)

The initial version of the first approach. Who's Joe?

Comment: Not one, not two, but three Vyxal bugs were found in the making of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 46 bytes

```ruby
->n{[z=(" "+?#*n)*n,[?#+(" "*n+?#)*n]*n,z]*$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOrrKVkNJQUnbXlkrT1MrTyfaXlkbJKCVBxQCCsQCxapitVT0a/9rGOrpmWrq5SYWVNdU1BSUlhQrpEVXxFqDWLX/AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 25 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

Port of [Jonah's excellent J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244097/64121).

```
" #"⊏˜·≠⌜´+⟜1(+⥊↑⟜1)¨1∾×˜
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgIiAjIuKKj8ucwrfiiaDijJzCtCvin5wxKCvipYrihpHin5wxKcKoMeKIvsOXy5wKCkbCqCAxK+KGlTQ=)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 69 bytes

```hs
f n=unlines[[" # "!!(0^mod x(n+1)+0^y)|x<-[0..n*n+n]]|y<-[0..n]++[0]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7Y0LyczL7U4OlpJQVlBSVFRwyAuNz9FoUIjT9tQU9sgrlKzpsJGN9pATy9PK087Lza2phLKjdXWjjaIjf2fm5iZp2CrUFBaElxS5JOnoKKQpmDyHwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 63 bytes

```
lambda n:"\n".join(n*(a+n*b)+a for a,b in[" #",*n*["# "]," #"])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY37XMSc5NSEhXyrJRi8pT0svIz8zTytDQStfO0kjS1ExXS8osUEnWSFDLzopUUlJV0tPK0opWUFZRidUDcWE2oMeogdZlAVQpFiXnpqRqGOuaaVgVFmXklGmkamZqa1hA2VPmCBRAaAA)

Comment: [60 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3bXISc5NSEhXyrKILijLzSjTytDQStfO0kjS1EzXT8osUEnWSFDLzopUUlJV0tPK0opWUFZRidUDc2FioGQogdZlAVQpFiXnpqRqGOuaaVmkamZrWECM1IeoWLIDQAA) by printing at each iteration instead of returning a newline-separated string.

Comment: @ophact does this count as "joined by newlines" which OP specifically asks for?

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that. Better not use my modification in that case...

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 machine code, 33 bytes

```
56 B8 20 0A B0 23 5A 52 AA 34 03 59 51 F3 AA 34 03 FF CA 75 F3 66 AB FF CE 79 E9 7A E4 88 17 59 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZJNb9swDIbP4q/gPASQFzdI030hbgZsPe@y04AkB0eSYxWKJEhOqyzIX59HuW0uu5AQ34cvKUjC@5u9EMPQxANy/FVwmO2N2zUGW2iXzB9jhyFqiGbJZrtTr3CefnytKC7mOc6/gyfp4J6wMWP5Dph3HoNMNb60ywSExN7FHbDkwki@YeKKiQQsKI//g1IJVOTCHu0fNDBaPb@WaTcqR/RUf/QKI@W8zTpIva1Qmuuc7N5DWWBZg0q9ChaLhwLPT05LbLnomvABY4Xa9mjL@gLwXlthjlLhfeyldrPuG0BWD422vIQzsNyEQcWj6defbhfbGlhLe/PRA1d4W1O6X@EXytNpCYx6WMtfOqo8hs4@EN7yYqI3dhI3tiChenXNwAWuyMb@bESnrULhpFoWWc6zEs2i9zjRUTo8v@E4mS9@k91pxfnRRr23SuJ40bIt12k63dI98bnTRiE/4TsySQ932fTqwCca87vHclwskXgZhr@iNc0@DjeHzx8p0O9ZEa/MPw)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes in RDI an address at which to place the result, as a null-terminated byte string, and takes the number n in RSI.

In assembly:

```
f:  push rsi            # Push n onto the stack.
sl: .byte 0xB8, 0x20, 0x0A  # These bytes combine with the next instruction to form
            #  mov eax, 0x23B00A20. In particular, the lowest byte (AL) is 0x20 (' ')
            #                           and the second-lowest byte (AH) is 0x0A ('\n'). 
pl: mov al, 0x23    # (Executed for the middle lines) Set AL to 0x23 ('#').
    pop rdx; push rdx   # Set RDX to n. (This is 2 bytes; mov edx, [rsp] would be 3.)
l:  stosb               # Write AL to the string, advancing the pointer.
    xor al, 3           # Change AL from ' ' to '#' or vice versa.
    pop rcx; push rcx   # Set RCX to n.
    rep stosb           # Write AL to the string RCX times, advancing the pointer.
    xor al, 3           # Change AL from ' ' to '#' or vice versa.
    dec edx             # Subtract 1 from EDX.
    jnz l               # If it's not zero, jump back. (Repeats n times.)
    stosw               # Write AL and AH ('\n') to the string, advancing the pointer.
    dec esi             # Subtract 1 from ESI.
    jns pl              # If it's not negative (which occurs n times),
                        #  jump back to make a line starting with '#'.
    jpe sl              # Jump back to make a line starting with ' '
                        #  if the sum of the eight low bits is even.
                        #  This is true for -1 (…11111111) but not for -2 (…11111110).
    mov [rdi], dl       # Add DL (the low byte of RDX), which is 0, to the string.
    pop rcx             # Take n off the stack.
    ret                 # Return.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 58 bytes

```powershell
param($n)($t=(' '+'#'*$n)*$n);,(('#'+' '*$n)*$n+'#')*$n;$t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9vyCxKDFXQyVPU0OlxFZDXUFdW11ZXQvIB2FrHQ0NIFcbKAwVAsmCaGuVkv@1XColqcUlzonFqcW2DhqGOkY6xjomOqY6ZppIMjWq1VxKnnkFpSVWCirxCgl5/qUlII4SlxrQCSrxXLX/AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 102 bytes

*shorter version thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!*

```c
i=-1,j;main(n){for(n+=scanf("%d",&n);j=i++<n;puts(""))for(;j-->n-n*n;putchar("# "[!(j%n)^(i^n&&i)]));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsIwEAXQq@hIw4zpLHQb40XEQhipTsBfaXUlnj2i28czvZq15ll3fU334mDIe5xmRsyLFYxM3YX6AEk1e4wHpMfruTCRyK@lqnqEYvt3u5WZabOi05prBxnYB4TgchZJn9b2Xw)

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 107 bytes

```c
main(i,j,n){scanf("%d",&n);++n;for(i=-1;i++<n;puts(""))for(j=-1;j++<n*n-n;putchar("# "[!(j%n)^(i^n&&i)]));}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjezcxMz8zQydbJ08jSri5MT89I0lFRTlHTU8jSttbXzrNPyizQybXUNrTO1tW3yrAtKS4o1lJQ0NUHiWSDxLJC4Vp4uWC45I7FIQ0lZQSlaUSNLNU8zTiMzLk9NLVMzVlPTuhZiJdTmJdGGBrFQNgA)

Indented version:

```c
main(i,j,n){
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ++n;
    for(i=-1;i++<n;puts(""))
        for(j=-1;j++<n*n-n;
            putchar("# "[!(j%n)^(i^n&&i)]));    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>71</s> 67 bytes

```
lambda n:"\n".join([t:=" "+f'{"#"*n} '*n,*["#"+f'{" "*n}#'*n]*n,t])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3nXMSc5NSEhXyrJRi8pT0svIz8zSiS6xslRSUtNPUq5WUlbTyahXUtfJ0tKKBHLCYAkhMGSgWCxQuidWEGqVfUJSZV6KRpmGoqckFYxshsY2R2CaaUG0LFkBoAA)

-4 bytes from @Unrelated String

Comment: Since this isn't recursive, you can drop the `f=` (leaving it as an anonymous function). You can also save a few parens with f-strings: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3nXMSc5NSEhXyrJRi8pT0svIz8zSiS6xslRSUtNPUq5WUlbTyahXUtfJ0tKKBHLCYAkhMGSgWCxQuidWEGqVfUJSZV6KRpmGoqckFYxshsY2R2CaaUG0LFkBoAA)

Comment: Ah cheers for that, kinda forgot you can just use lambdas as anonymous functions...

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 37 bytes

Prompts for n. Index origin = 0

```
' #'[(v,0)∘.≠((n×n+1)⍴v←0,(n←⎕)⍴1),0]
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog APL Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tv7qCsnq0RpmOgeajjhl6jzoXaGjkHZ6ep22o@ah3SxlInY5GHpACagOJGGrqGMT@B@rk@p/GZcilrqDOlcZlBKWNobQJFwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＮθＦθＧＨ+→⁺²θ⁺ ×θ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05orLb9IAchQCMjPqUzPz/PIz8nJL9ew0tZRsArKTM8o0VEIyCkt1jDSUSjUhLKVFJR0FEIyc1OLNQp1FJSUlTQ1Na3//zf@r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
Ｆθ
```

Repeat `n` times...

```
ＧＨ+→⁺²θ⁺ ×θ#
```

... draw a hollow polygon using the directions Right, Down, Left, Up, Right, of size `n+2`, using a string consisting of a space and `n` `#`s. Each polygon therefore starts at the top left of the "circle" and finishes at the top right, ready to start the next one.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
WBtTh!-GtQ*Q:Z)Zc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9ypJCRDUde9JFAr0CpKMyr5/39jAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D/cqSQkQ1HXvSRQK9AqSjMq@b9BcoRLVEXIf0MuIy5jLhMA).

#### Explanation

Consider input `n = 3` as an example.

```
WB     % Implicit input: n. 2^n, convert to binary.
       % STACK: [1 0 0 0] 
tTh    % Duplicate, push 1, concatenate horizontally
       % STACK: [1 0 0 0], [1 0 0 0 1]
!-     % Transpose, subtract element-wise with broadcast
       % STACK:  [0 -1 -1 -1
                  1  0  0  0
                  1  0  0  0
                  1  0  0  0
                  0 -1 -1 -1]
GtQ*Q: % Push n, duplicate, add 1, multiply, add 1: gives n^2+n+1. Range (1-based)
       % STACK:  [0 -1 -1 -1
                  1  0  0  0
                  1  0  0  0
                  1  0  0  0
                  0 -1 -1 -1], [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13]
Z)     % Horizontal indexing (1-based, modular)
       % STACK: [0 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1  0
                 1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
                 1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
                 1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1                    
                 0 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1  0]
Zc     % Convert non-zeros to '#'. Implicit display (char(0) is displayed as space)
       % STACK: [' ### ### ### '
                 '#   #   #   #'
                 '#   #   #   #'
                 '#   #   #   #'
                 ' ### ### ### ']
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
‘ð;×Ż€⁸ḍn€/ị⁾# Y
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4zDG6wPTz@6@1HTmkeNOx7u6M0DsvQf7u5@1LhPWSHy////xgA)**

```
‘ð;×Ż€⁸ḍn€/ị⁾# Y - Main Link: integer, N
‘                - increment -> N+1
 ð               - start a new dyadic chain - f(N+1, N)
   ×             - multiply -> (N+1)×N
  ;              - concatenate -> [N+1, (N+1)×N]
    Ż€           - zero range each -> [[0..N+1], [0..(N+1)×N]
      ⁸          - chain's left argument -> N+1
       ḍ         - divides? (vectorises) -> [[1,0,...,0,1], [1,0,...,0,1,0,...,0,1,0,...,1]]
          /      - reduce by:
         €       -   for each:
        n        -     not equal (vectorises)
           ị⁾#.  - index into "# " (vectorises)
               Y - join with newline characters
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>93</s> 82 bytes

Jonah's [observation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244097/111305) that this pattern can be formed easily with an XOR table intrigued me, and I wanted to see if this would produce something short in Python. Unfortunately, I couldn't come up with a good way to build the required patterns golfily, and the result clocks in 30 bytes longer than the other python answer here:

```python
lambda x:"\n".join("".join(" #"[i^j]for i in[0,*[1]*x]*x+[0])for j in[0,*[1]*x,0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCSikmT0kvKz8zT0MJSmsoKSjpKCkraUZnKtpmxablFylkKmTmqRuoFquraqgbqmtVaGpVaKsbqGuC5LKgcgZwSc3/BUWZeSUaaRqGmppcMLYREtsYiW0CVA8A)

Edit -11 bytes: from [@DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)'s idea of using lists of ints instead of strings.

### Explanation

```python
lambda x:
                                                                   for j in [0,*[1]*x,0]  ## Builds the list [0,1,1,...0], with x 1s, and loops over it
                                         for i in [0,*[1]*x]*x+[0]                        ## Builds the list [0,1,1,...0,1,1,...0,....], i.e. [0,1...] with x 1s, repeated x times, with an extra 0 at the end
                           (" ","#")[i^j]                                                 ## '#' if i xor j, else ' '
                   "".join(                                       )                       ## .join the characters of this line
         "\n".join(                                                                     ) ## Encapsulate it in a list for output
```

Comment: Nice approach--too bad it's not shorter. Here's [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCSikmT0kvKz8zT0MJRisoK0VnxmXFpuUXKWQqZOZFG@hoRRvGalUAkXa0QawmSCILWUIHKPi/oCgzr0QjTcNQU5MLxjZCYhsjsU00Nf8DAA) using lists of ints instead of strings.

Comment: oh nice one @DLosc! for a while I had been experimenting with a truly bizarre idea using `bin()` and the fact that `1` and `b` have the same codepoint mod 49, but it, rather unsurprisingly, didnt really pan out

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 43 bytes

```perl
say$_=$".('#'x$_.$")x$_,($/.y/ #/# /r)x"@F"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIl3lZFSU9DXVm9QiVeT0VJE0jpaKjo61XqKyjrKyvoF2lWKDm4Kf3/b/wvv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaHBf92CRAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 12, 83 bytes

```
StringRiffle[StringJoin/@Table[If[#∣i⊻#∣j,"#"," "],{j,0,#},{i,0,#2#}]&[#+1,#],"\n"]&
```

Uses the obvious divisibility trick, and *Mathematica*'s good unicode parsing

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H55ZkhFdnVaal2z7P7ikKDMvPSgzLS0nNRrC8crPzNN3CElMAop4pkUrP@pYnPmoazeIztJRUlbSUVJQitWpztIx0FGu1anOBNFGyrWxatHK2oY6yrE6SjF5SrFq/2t1AoDGlThogWzSdwhKzEtPdTA0iP0PAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [flax](https://github.com/PyGamer0/flax) `C`, <sup>21 19</sup> 18 bytes

```
₊ #iZŻ≠⌜ŻF₎⍴⊂µ¬W1⍪
```

<s>Not happy with the byte count...</s>

Slightly better.

-1 byte by implicit joining of newlines.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 79 bytes

```
.+
$*
1
$_¶
^
$%' #¶
¶$
¶$%` #
\b¶
# ¶
%(`1
$_¶
1(?=.*(.))
$1
.¶

(.+)(.).
$2$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLkEsl/tA2rjguFVV1BWUg69A2FRBWTVBQ5opJAgooKwAJVY0EqEpDDXtbPS0NPU1NLhVDLj2gCJeGnrYmUECPS8VIxfD/f2MA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1
$_¶
```

Replicate the line of `n` `1`s `n` times.

```
^
$%' #¶
```

Prefix a line of `n` `1`s with a suffix of  `#`. This indicates the pattern for the first line.

```
¶$
¶$%` #
```

Append another such line.

```
\b¶
# ¶
```

Append `#`  to the original `n` lines. These indicate the pattern for the intermediate lines.

```
%(`
```

Apply the rest of the script separately to each line.

```
1
$_¶
```

Repeat each line `n` times. This also leaves an extra copy of the two pattern characters on a line on its own.

```
1(?=.*(.))
$1
```

Replace each `1` with the last character on the line.

```
.¶
```

Delete last character on each line as it is joined with the next line.

```
(.+)(.).
$2$1
```

Move the final copy of the first pattern character to the start of the entire line and delete the final copy of the second pattern character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 40 bytes

```
.+
*$( $&*#)¶$&*$(*$(#$&* )#¶)$&*$( $&*#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS0tFQ0FFTUtZ89A2IKWiAUTKQIaCpvKhbZpgEbD0//@GXEZcxlwmAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Just some boring string repetition. The final line parses as `$&*$( $&*#)¶$&*$($&*$(#$&* )#¶)$&*$( $&*#)` where the `$()` is a grouping construct and `$&*` repeats the character or group the number of times given by the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>66</s> 65 bytes

```javascript
n=>(t=(r=s=>s.repeat(n))(' '+r('#'))+`
`)+r(r('#'+r(' '))+`#
`)+t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZchLCoAgEADQfacIXDhDJPRZBDGeJQmLIlRUvL6Vu2j53qmSCqs/XGzTlDfKhiREAk@BZBBeO60iGETgNW88cMYRm6Va8EHhm3VJ9m7MqzXBXlpcdocNOsS5@lb/r@Ff41P5Bg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 86 bytes

```hs
t=(.cycle).take
f n=unlines$t(n+2)[t(n^2+n+1)[" # "!!(x+y)|x<-l]|y<-l]where l=1:t n[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcVBCoMwEADAu69YrYeEoFS9leYVHoOFICuK20V0RQP@PbaXmdFvMxLFKFaVfegJdSl@xmQAtjvTxLjlotjU2v361IZNpV0GD8jSVJ0m6Ot8F9Rd4e8x4opAtnoJsHt28esnBgvLLq2s@QBNvAE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Headascii](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass#Headascii), 121 bytes

```
+OUO{^)+E:ROD-}.UOD++++[]]]][]]O[UO{N-)!@++E:]PUO{^):]+++PD-};}.UO)++++E:U[{N-)+++E:]+++PUO{^):]PD-};}.OUUO{^)@+E:RO!D-}.
```

Whew!

Try it [here!](https://replit.com/@thejonymyster/HA23)
Code will have to be copied and executed as shown:

```js
erun("+OUO{^)+E:ROD-}.UOD++++[]]]][]]O[UO{N-)!@++E:]PUO{^):]+++PD-};}.UO)++++E:U[{N-)+++E:]+++PUO{^):]PD-};}.OUUO{^)@+E:RO!D-}.","your input here")
```

But also, it takes input by charcode, so for example if you wanted to input 4, you'd type

```js
"\u0004"
```

Which I think is perfectly valid :D

Code breakdown:

```
+OUO{^)+E:ROD-}. block 0
+O               push 1 to global as a flag
  UO             get n/push n to global
  U {^)  :  D-}  loop n times
          RO       push n to global
       +E      . goto block 1
     
UOD++++[]]]][]]O[UO{N-)!@++E:]PUO{^):]+++PD-};}. block 1
UOD                                              push flag to global
   ++++[]]]][]]O                                 push 32 to global
                [                                and store it
                 UO                              push n to global
                   {N-)     :  U              }  loop n times
                             ]P                    append 32 to string
                               UO                  push n to global
                               U {^):     D-};     loop n times
                                     ]+++P           append 35 to string
                       !@                        print string w/trailing
                                                 newline and clear string
                         ++E                   . goto block 2
            
UO)++++E:U[{N-)+++E:]+++PUO{^):]PD-};}. block 2
UO)                                      if flag is 0
   ++++E                                  goto block 5
        :                               else
         U[                               store 32
           {N-)    :     U           }    loop n plus 1 times
                    ]+++P                   append 35 to string
                         UO                 push n to global
                           {^):  D-};       loop n times
                               ]P             append 32 to string
               +++E                   .   goto block 3

OUUO{^)@+E:RO!D-}. block 3
O                  push 0 to global as flag
 U                 discard previous flag state
  UO               push n to global
  U {^)   :   D-}  loop n times
           RO        push n to global
             !       print string w/trailing newline
       @           clear string
        +E       . goto block 1
        
block 4 is empty
```

Using the global array length as an extra register is a fun trick i just learned doing this :)